# Non-Uniform Random Number Generator Implementation?

Tags: statistics, random, numbers

I need a random number generator that picks numbers over a specified range with a programmable mean.

For example, I need to pick numbers between 2 and 14 and I need the average of the random numbers to be 5.

I use random number generators a lot. Usually I just need a uniform distribution.

I don't even know what to call this type of distribution.

Thank you for any assistance or insight you can provide.

Comment: Are you sure that you provided enough information about the distribution? I believe mean value is not enough. Consider this example: let's say we generate random numbers from `{0, 1, 2}` with 1 mean. Now take a look at these two generators: `Generator1 (0: 40%, 1: 20%, 2: 40%)`, `Generator2 (0:10%, 1: 80%, 2:10%)`. For both of them average result would be 1.

Comment: A near duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977354/generating-non-uniform-random-numbers. And non-flat pseudo-random distributions are a standard topic that has been addressed more than once on SO. Give more information and we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: If the target distribution is not easily represented by a integrable PDF look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423006/how-do-i-generate-points-that-match-a-histogram

Comment: WRT what GrzegorzOledzki says, you can meet the requirements as stated using uniform distribution except making 2 happen 14 times more often than the other values - ie uniform selection from a list with 14 repeats of the 2. Pretty easy, but not likely to be appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

You might be able to use a [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), if you're happy with the shape of that distribution.  Set n=12 and p=0.25.  This will give you a value between 0 and 12 with a mean of 3.  Just add 2 to each result to get the range and mean you are looking for.

**Edit:** As for implementation, you can probably find a library for your chosen language that supports non-uniform distributions (I've [written one myself for Java](http://maths.uncommons.org)).

A binomial distribution can be approximated fairly easily using a uniform RNG.  Simply perform *n* trials and record the number of successes.  So if you have n=10 and p=0.5, it's just like flipping a coin 10 times in a row and counting the number of heads.   For p=0.25 just generate uniformly-distributed values between 0 and 3 and only count zeros as successes.

If you want a more efficient implementation, there is a clever algorithm hidden away in the exercises of volume 2 of Knuth's The Art of Computer Programming.

Comment: the link to ["(I've written one myself for Java)."](https://uncommons-maths.dev.java.net/) is not available

Answer (score 3):

You haven't said what distribution you are after. Regarding your specific example, a function which produced a uniform distribution between 2 and 8 would satisfy your requirements, strictly as you have written them :)

Comment: I think the OP intends for values from 9-14 to have some probability of being selected.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a non-uniform distribution of the random number, then you might have to implement some sort of mapping, e.g:

```
// returns a number between 0..5 with a custom distribution
int MyCustomDistribution()
{
  int r = rand(100); // random number between 0..100
  if (r < 10) return 1;
  if (r < 30) return 2;
  if (r < 42) return 3;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [Wikipedia sub-article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator#Non-uniform_generators) about non-uniform generators, it would seem you want to apply the output of a uniform pseudorandom number generator to an area distribution that meets the desired mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a non-uniform PRNG from a uniform one.  This makes sense, as you can imagine taking a uniform PRNG that returns 0,1,2 and create a new, non-uniform PRNG by returning 0 for values 0,1 and 1 for the value 2.

There is more to it if you want specific characteristics on the distribution of your new, non-uniform PRNG.  This is covered on [the Wikipedia page on PRNGs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator#Non-uniform_generators), and the [Ziggurat algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziggurat_algorithm) is specifically mentioned.

With those clues you should be able to search up some code.

Answer (score 0):

My first idea would be:

- generate numbers in the range 0..1
- scale to the range -9..9 ( x-0.5; x*18)
- shift range by 5 -> -4 .. 14 (add 5)
- truncate the range to 2..14 (discard numbers < 2)

that should give you numbers in the range you want.

Comment: But as you discard the numbers < 2 your average moves upward away from 5 doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You need a distributed / weighted random number generator.  [Here's a reference](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract;jsessionid=E1B1F4C69946FEB4C0D77D0E4D1100E4.tomcat1?fromPage=online&aid=1457336) to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

```
Assign all numbers equal probabilities,
```

while currentAverage not equal to intendedAverage (whithin possible margin)

```
 pickedNumber = pick one of the possible numbers (at random, uniform probability, if you pick intendedAverage pick again)

 if (pickedNumber is greater than intendedAverage and currentAverage<intendedAverage) or (pickedNumber is less than intendedAverage and currentAverage>intendedAverage)

   increase pickedNumber's probability by delta at the expense of all others, conserving sum=100%

 else

   decrease pickedNumber's probability by delta to the benefit of all others, conserving sum=100%

 end if

 delta=0.98*delta (the rate of decrease of delta should probably be experimented with)
```

end while