# How can I get weighted random selections from an array in Perl?

Tags: perl, random

I need to random some elements from an array. I'm doing that by randomizing the index `$array[int(rand(100))]`. I want some of the elements to appear more often. How do I do it?

I thought of a stupid solution of having those elements duplicated several times in the array, but I'm sure you guys can do better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this sub' gets an array of element and weight -A(10)B(30)C(5)-and random one of the elements according the weights.

sub we_rand {

```
my $line=$_[0];#get the elements array
my @b = split(/\(\d+\)/,$line);#b now holds each elemnet from the array
my @a = "";
my $i=0;
my $tmp;
    while ($line=~m/(\(\d+\)+)/g) {
        $tmp=$1;#temp gets the weight
        if ($tmp=~m/\d+/g) {
            if ($i>0){
            $a[$i]=$&+$a[$i-1];#if weight is grather then 0 -each cell of
            #a sums up the wheights up to it 
            }
            else {
            $a[$i]=$&;
            }
        }
        $i++;
         }
        if ($i>1){
            my $n=int(rand($a[$i-1])+1);#rand a number in the boundries of
            #the total weight of all the elements
            my $s=scalar(@b);
            #go through a and compare to the randomized num-then take the
            #element from b
            for ( $i=0;$i<scalar(@b);$i++){
                if($n<=$a[$i])
                {
                    $c=$b[$i];
                last;
                    }
            }
        } else {
        $c=$b[0];#if only one element
        }

        return $c;
```

### }

you call the sub' like this:

my $rand=we_rand(A(10)B(30)C(5)D(17));
-#$rand=B

Answer (score 5):

You want to generate a [weighted random sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352670/weighted-random-selection-with-and-without-replacement). The linked question covers both with and without replacement.

Answer (score 3):

Seems that a rather natural way involves setting up a binary search. Let's say a bunch of people are enrolled in a raffle, where people are allowed to submit their names as many times as they want. We have the following names with the following number of submissions:

- Juliet: 2
- Jenny: 11
- Jessica: 7
- Jan: 1
- Jane: 1
- Jean: 5

Now if we want to randomly select a name out of the bag, we just assign each name a range starting from 0:

- Juliet: 0, 1
- Jenny: 2, 12
- Jessica: 13, 19
- Jan: 20, 20
- Jane: 21, 21
- Jean: 22, 26

Alright, so we have an array of *adjacent ranges*, were each range is between 0 and 26. We use a modified binary search to find our target item (pseudocode):

```
let raffle := { Juliet: 0, 1;
                Jenny: 2, 12;
                Jessica: 13, 19;
                Jan: 20, 20;
                Jane: 21, 21;
                Jean: 22, 26 }

let search minIndex maxIndex rangeValue =
    if minIndex > maxIndex then
        failwith "Not found"

    let selectedIndex = (minIndex + maxIndex) / 2
    let item = raffle[selectedIndex]

    if item.range.min >= rangeValue && item.range.max <= rangeValue
        return item.name
    elif item.range.min < rangeValue
        return search minIndex (selectedIndex - 1) rangeValue
    else
        return search (selectedIndex + 1) maxIndex rangeValue
```

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://www.av8n.com/physics/arbitrary-probability.htm) provides the theory for generating random numbers from arbitrary distribution.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the frequency with which you want the random numbers to appear, you could use the rand() function. Let's say you want the number 0 to appear 33% of the time, and 1 to appear the other 66%. Then you would check if rand() < 0.33, and return some index. Otherwise, return another index. This is just one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to have a structure similar to the following: (pardon my language, I don't actually know Perl all that well)

```
[
  (1, 10),
  (2, 50),
  (3, 80),
  (4, 100)
]
```

Then when you get the value from `int(rand(100))` you can compare it to each of the second elements in turn and return the first element.

Answer (score 0):

The most general solution is a function that acts as an (inverse) [cumulative distribution function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function): a function that maps from a (uniform) distribution from 0.0 to 1.0 to whatever distribution that you want.

Juliet gave an excellent way to implement one of them.