# A weighted version of random.choice

Tags: python, optimization, random

I needed to write a weighted version of random.choice (each element in the list has a different probability for being selected).  This is what I came up with:

```
def weightedChoice(choices):
    """Like random.choice, but each element can have a different chance of
    being selected.

    choices can be any iterable containing iterables with two items each.
    Technically, they can have more than two items, the rest will just be
    ignored.  The first item is the thing being chosen, the second item is
    its weight.  The weights can be any numeric values, what matters is the
    relative differences between them.
    """
    space = {}
    current = 0
    for choice, weight in choices:
        if weight > 0:
            space[current] = choice
            current += weight
    rand = random.uniform(0, current)
    for key in sorted(space.keys() + [current]):
        if rand < key:
            return choice
        choice = space[key]
    return None
```

This function seems overly complex to me, and ugly.  I'm hoping everyone here can offer some suggestions on improving it or alternate ways of doing this.  Efficiency isn't as important to me as code cleanliness and readability.

Answer (score 424, accepted):

Since version 1.7.0, NumPy has a [`choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) function that supports probability distributions.

```
from numpy.random import choice
draw = choice(list_of_candidates, number_of_items_to_pick,
              p=probability_distribution)
```

Note that `probability_distribution` is a sequence in the same order of `list_of_candidates`. You can also use the keyword `replace=False` to change the behavior so that drawn items are not replaced.

Comment: By my testing, this is an order of magnitude slower than `random.choices` for individual calls. If you need a lot of random results, it's really important to pick them all at once by adjusting `number_of_items_to_pick`. If you do so, it's an order of magnitude faster.

Comment: This doesn't work with tuples etc ("ValueError: a must be 1-dimensional"), so in that case one can ask numpy to pick the *index* into the list, i.e. `len(list_of_candidates)`, and then do `list_of_candidates[draw]`

Comment: Now you got choices method in the random module

Comment: [Document](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/random.html#random.choices) says `choices()` uses floating point arithmetic for **increasing speed** and `choice()` uses integer arithmetic for **reducing bias**. This might be the reason behind `choices()` being a faster option compared to `choice()`

Comment: How does it behave if weights are given **and** `replace=False`? I'm not sure that this problem is well-defined, i.e. what the relative probabilities of results ought to be.

Answer (score 397):

Since Python 3.6 there is a method [`choices`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/random.html#random.choices) from the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/random.html#module-random) module.

```
In [1]: import random

In [2]: random.choices(
...:     population=[['a','b'], ['b','a'], ['c','b']],
...:     weights=[0.2, 0.2, 0.6],
...:     k=10
...: )

Out[2]:
[['c', 'b'],
 ['c', 'b'],
 ['b', 'a'],
 ['c', 'b'],
 ['c', 'b'],
 ['b', 'a'],
 ['c', 'b'],
 ['b', 'a'],
 ['c', 'b'],
 ['c', 'b']]
```

Note that `random.choices` will sample *with replacement*, per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/random.html#random.choices):

> Return a `k` sized list of elements chosen from the population with replacement.

Note for completeness of answer:

> When a sampling unit is drawn from a finite population and is returned
> to that population, after its characteristic(s) have been recorded,
> before the next unit is drawn, the sampling is said to be "with
> replacement". It basically means each element may be chosen more than
> once.

If you need to sample without replacement, then as [@ronan-paixão's brilliant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26196078/3124746) states, you can use [`numpy.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html), whose `replace` argument controls such behaviour.

Comment: This is so much faster than numpy.random.choice .  Picking from a list of 8 weighted items 10,000 times, numpy.random.choice took 0.3286 sec where as random.choices took 0.0416 sec, about 8x faster.

Comment: @AntonCodes This example is cherry picked. numpy is going to have some constant-time overhead that `random.choices` doesn't, so of course it's slower on a miniscule list of 8 items, and if you're choosing 10k times from such a list, you're right. But for cases when the list is larger (depending on how you're testing, I see break points between 100-300 elements), `np.random.choice` begins outperforming `random.choices` by a fairly wide gap. For example, including the normalization step along with the numpy call, I get a nearly 4x speedup over `random.choices` for a list of 10k elements.

Comment: This should be the new answer based on the performance improvement that @AntonCodes reported.

Comment: It would probably better this answer to not have the `population` be a list of lists, which briefly confused me. Just a simple list of strings or ints would be a fine illustration and be a better MWE, imo

Answer (score 144):

```
def weighted_choice(choices):
   total = sum(w for c, w in choices)
   r = random.uniform(0, total)
   upto = 0
   for c, w in choices:
      if upto + w >= r:
         return c
      upto += w
   assert False, "Shouldn't get here"
```

Comment: You can drop an operation and save a sliver of time by reversing the statements inside the for loop: `upto +=w; if upto > r`

Comment: save a variable by deleting upto and just decrementing r by the weight each time. The comparison is then `if r < 0`

Comment: @JnBrymn You need to check `r <= 0`. Consider an input set of 1 items, and a roll of 1.0. The assertion will fail then. I corrected that error in the answer.

Comment: I used this in some of my code and ran your own coverage tool. It gave me: "did not return from function as the loop did not finish". Any way round that to get 100% test coverage? Should I open a bug report or a separate question for this?

Comment: @Sardathrion you could use a pragma to mark the for loop as partial: `# pragma: no branch`

Comment: Is this a "resampling wheel" as explained by Sebastien Thurn in the Udacity AI4R free class?  Lesson 8, video 21, I cannot post a link as I'm logged in with my account.

Comment: @mLstudent33 I dont use Udacity.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting: If you're pulling the data from a database, the `weighted_choice` function should be slightly faster if `choices` are sorted in descending order compared to an ascending order (of the numeric value that's being summed here). So if you're sorting the results in your DB query, it is beneficial to have them in descending order. This is just something I encountered when getting the top N most suitable candidates from a DB and then doing the weighted random choice. Maybe someone else will have a similar use case.

Comment: @moooeeeep that case happens with probability 0 though (I know this was posted forever ago haha)

Answer (score 84):

1. Arrange the weights into a
   cumulative distribution.
2. Use **random.random()** to pick a random
   float `0.0 <= x < total`.
3. Search the
   distribution using **bisect.bisect** as
   shown in the example at http://docs.python.org/dev/library/bisect.html#other-examples.

```
from random import random
from bisect import bisect

def weighted_choice(choices):
    values, weights = zip(*choices)
    total = 0
    cum_weights = []
    for w in weights:
        total += w
        cum_weights.append(total)
    x = random() * total
    i = bisect(cum_weights, x)
    return values[i]

>>> weighted_choice([("WHITE",90), ("RED",8), ("GREEN",2)])
'WHITE'
```

If you need to make more than one choice, split this into two functions, one to build the cumulative weights and another to bisect to a random point.

Comment: This is more efficient than Ned's answer. Basically, instead of doing a linear (O(n)) search through the choices, he's doing a binary search (O(log n)). +1!

Comment: tuple index out of range if random() happens to return 1.0

Comment: This still runs in `O(n)` because of the cumulative distribution calculation.

Comment: This solution is better in the case where multiple calls to weighted_choice are needed for the same set of choices.  In that case you can create the cumulative sum once and do a binary search on each call.

Comment: @JonVaughan `random()` *can't* return 1.0. Per the docs, it returns a result in the half-open interval `[0.0, 1.0)`, which is to say that it *can* return exactly 0.0, but *can't* return exactly 1.0. The largest value it can return is 0.99999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875 (which Python prints as 0.9999999999999999, and is the largest 64-bit float less than 1).

Comment: @JonVaughan ... however, the overall thrust of your concern is valid, since many very tiny values of `total` satisfy `0.9999999999999999 * total == total`. For instance, `1e-320 * 0.9999999999999999 == 1e-320`.

Answer (score 23):

If you don't mind using numpy, you can use [numpy.random.choice](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html).

For example:

```
import numpy

items  = [["item1", 0.2], ["item2", 0.3], ["item3", 0.45], ["item4", 0.05]
elems = [i[0] for i in items]
probs = [i[1] for i in items]

trials = 1000
results = [0] * len(items)
for i in range(trials):
    res = numpy.random.choice(items, p=probs)  #This is where the item is selected!
    results[items.index(res)] += 1
results = [r / float(trials) for r in results]
print "item\texpected\tactual"
for i in range(len(probs)):
    print "%s\t%0.4f\t%0.4f" % (items[i], probs[i], results[i])
```

If you know how many selections you need to make in advance, you can do it without a loop like this:

```
numpy.random.choice(items, trials, p=probs)
```

Answer (score 20):

As of Python `v3.6`, [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) could be used to return a `list` of elements of specified size from the given population with optional weights.

> `random.choices(population, weights=None, *, cum_weights=None, k=1)`

- *population* : `list` containing unique observations. (If empty, raises `IndexError`)
- *weights* : More precisely relative weights required to make selections.
- *cum_weights* : cumulative weights required to make selections.
- *k* : size(`len`) of the `list` to be outputted. (Default `len()=1`)

---

***Few Caveats:***

1) It makes use of weighted sampling with replacement so the drawn items would be later replaced. The values in the weights sequence in itself do not matter, but their relative ratio does.

Unlike `np.random.choice` which can only take on probabilities as weights and also which must ensure summation of individual probabilities upto 1 criteria, there are no such regulations here. As long as they belong to numeric types (`int/float/fraction` except `Decimal` type) , these would still perform.

```
>>> import random
# weights being integers
>>> random.choices(["white", "green", "red"], [12, 12, 4], k=10)
['green', 'red', 'green', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'green', 'white', 'red', 'white']
# weights being floats
>>> random.choices(["white", "green", "red"], [.12, .12, .04], k=10)
['white', 'white', 'green', 'green', 'red', 'red', 'white', 'green', 'white', 'green']
# weights being fractions
>>> random.choices(["white", "green", "red"], [12/100, 12/100, 4/100], k=10)
['green', 'green', 'white', 'red', 'green', 'red', 'white', 'green', 'green', 'green']
```

2) If neither *weights* nor *cum_weights* are specified, selections are made with equal probability.  If a *weights* sequence is supplied, it must be the same length as the *population* sequence.

Specifying both *weights* and *cum_weights* raises a `TypeError`.

```
>>> random.choices(["white", "green", "red"], k=10)
['white', 'white', 'green', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'green']
```

3) *cum_weights* are typically a result of [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) function which are really handy in such situations.

> <sub>From the documentation linked:</sub>
>
> Internally, the relative weights are converted to cumulative weights
>   before making selections, so supplying the cumulative weights saves
>   work.

So, either supplying `weights=[12, 12, 4]` or `cum_weights=[12, 24, 28]` for our contrived case produces the same outcome and the latter seems to be more faster / efficient.

Answer (score 17):

Crude, but may be sufficient:

```
import random
weighted_choice = lambda s : random.choice(sum(([v]*wt for v,wt in s),[]))
```

Does it work?

```
# define choices and relative weights
choices = [("WHITE",90), ("RED",8), ("GREEN",2)]

# initialize tally dict
tally = dict.fromkeys(choices, 0)

# tally up 1000 weighted choices
for i in xrange(1000):
    tally[weighted_choice(choices)] += 1

print tally.items()
```

Prints:

```
[('WHITE', 904), ('GREEN', 22), ('RED', 74)]
```

Assumes that all weights are integers.  They don't have to add up to 100, I just did that to make the test results easier to interpret. (If weights are floating point numbers, multiply them all by 10 repeatedly until all weights >= 1.)

```
weights = [.6, .2, .001, .199]
while any(w < 1.0 for w in weights):
    weights = [w*10 for w in weights]
weights = map(int, weights)
```

Comment: Nice, I'm not sure I can assume all weights are integers, though.

Comment: Seems like your objects would be duplicated in this example. That'd be inefficient (and so is the function for converting weights to integers). Nevertheless, this solution is a good one-liner if the integer weights are small.

Comment: Primitives will be duplicated, but objects will only have references duplicated, not the objects themselves.  (this is why you can't create a list of  lists using `[[]]*10` - all the elements in the outer list point to the same list.

Comment: @PaulMcG No; nothing but references will ever be duplicated. Python's type system has no concept of primitives. You can confirm that even with e.g. an `int` you're still getting lots of references to the same object by doing something like `[id(x) for x in ([99**99] * 100)]` and observe that `id` returns the same memory address on every call.

Answer (score 16):

If you have a weighted dictionary instead of a list you can write this

```
items = { "a": 10, "b": 5, "c": 1 } 
random.choice([k for k in items for dummy in range(items[k])])
```

Note that `[k for k in items for dummy in range(items[k])]` produces this list `['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']`

Comment: This works for small total population values, but not for large datasets (e.g. US population by state would end up creating a working list with 300 million items in it).

Comment: @Ryan Indeed. It also doesn't work for non-integer weights, which are another realistic scenario (e.g. if you have your weights expressed as probabilities of selection).

Answer (score 14):

Here's is the version that is being included in the standard library for Python 3.6:

```
import itertools as _itertools
import bisect as _bisect

class Random36(random.Random):
    "Show the code included in the Python 3.6 version of the Random class"

    def choices(self, population, weights=None, *, cum_weights=None, k=1):
        """Return a k sized list of population elements chosen with replacement.

        If the relative weights or cumulative weights are not specified,
        the selections are made with equal probability.

        """
        random = self.random
        if cum_weights is None:
            if weights is None:
                _int = int
                total = len(population)
                return [population[_int(random() * total)] for i in range(k)]
            cum_weights = list(_itertools.accumulate(weights))
        elif weights is not None:
            raise TypeError('Cannot specify both weights and cumulative weights')
        if len(cum_weights) != len(population):
            raise ValueError('The number of weights does not match the population')
        bisect = _bisect.bisect
        total = cum_weights[-1]
        return [population[bisect(cum_weights, random() * total)] for i in range(k)]
```

Source:  https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/random.py#l340

Answer (score 10):

A very basic and easy approach for a weighted choice is the following:

```
np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C'], p=[0.3, 0.4, 0.3])
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import numpy as np
w=np.array([ 0.4,  0.8,  1.6,  0.8,  0.4])
np.random.choice(w, p=w/sum(w))
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm probably too late to contribute anything useful, but here's a simple, short, and very efficient snippet:

```
def choose_index(probabilies):
    cmf = probabilies[0]
    choice = random.random()
    for k in xrange(len(probabilies)):
        if choice <= cmf:
            return k
        else:
            cmf += probabilies[k+1]
```

No need to sort your probabilities or create a vector with your cmf, and it terminates once it finds its choice. Memory: O(1), time: O(N), with average running time ~ N/2.

If you have weights, simply add one line:

```
def choose_index(weights):
    probabilities = weights / sum(weights)
    cmf = probabilies[0]
    choice = random.random()
    for k in xrange(len(probabilies)):
        if choice <= cmf:
            return k
        else:
            cmf += probabilies[k+1]
```

Comment: Several things are wrong with this. Superficially, there are some typoed variable names and there's no rationale given for using this over, say, `np.random.choice`. But more interestingly, there's a failure mode where this raises an exception. Doing `probabilities = weights / sum(weights)` doesn't guarantee that `probabilities` will sum to 1; for instance, if `weights` is `[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]` then `probabilities` will only sum to 0.9999999999999998, smaller than the largest possible return value of `random.random` (which is 0.9999999999999999). Then `choice <= cmf` is never be satisfied.

Answer (score 3):

If your list of weighted choices is relatively static, and you want frequent sampling, you can do one O(N) preprocessing step, and then do the selection in O(1), using the functions in [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29722230/10396).

```
# run only when `choices` changes.
preprocessed_data = prep(weight for _,weight in choices)

# O(1) selection
value = choices[sample(preprocessed_data)][0]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you happen to have Python 3, and are afraid of installing `numpy` or writing your own loops, you could do:

```
import itertools, bisect, random

def weighted_choice(choices):
   weights = list(zip(*choices))[1]
   return choices[bisect.bisect(list(itertools.accumulate(weights)),
                                random.uniform(0, sum(weights)))][0]
```

Because you can build *anything* out of a bag of plumbing adaptors! Although... I must admit that Ned's answer, while slightly longer, is easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

I looked the pointed other thread and came up with this variation in my coding style, this returns the index of choice for purpose of tallying, but it is simple to return the string ( commented return alternative):

```
import random
import bisect

try:
    range = xrange
except:
    pass

def weighted_choice(choices):
    total, cumulative = 0, []
    for c,w in choices:
        total += w
        cumulative.append((total, c))
    r = random.uniform(0, total)
    # return index
    return bisect.bisect(cumulative, (r,))
    # return item string
    #return choices[bisect.bisect(cumulative, (r,))][0]

# define choices and relative weights
choices = [("WHITE",90), ("RED",8), ("GREEN",2)]

tally = [0 for item in choices]

n = 100000
# tally up n weighted choices
for i in range(n):
    tally[weighted_choice(choices)] += 1

print([t/sum(tally)*100 for t in tally])
```

Answer (score 2):

A general solution:

```
import random
def weighted_choice(choices, weights):
    total = sum(weights)
    treshold = random.uniform(0, total)
    for k, weight in enumerate(weights):
        total -= weight
        if total < treshold:
            return choices[k]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another version of weighted_choice that uses numpy. Pass in the weights vector and it will return an array of 0's containing a 1 indicating which bin was chosen. The code defaults to just making a single draw but you can pass in the number of draws to be made and the counts per bin drawn will be returned.

If the weights vector does not sum to 1, it will be normalized so that it does.

```
import numpy as np

def weighted_choice(weights, n=1):
    if np.sum(weights)!=1:
        weights = weights/np.sum(weights)

    draws = np.random.random_sample(size=n)

    weights = np.cumsum(weights)
    weights = np.insert(weights,0,0.0)

    counts = np.histogram(draws, bins=weights)
    return(counts[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

There is lecture on this by Sebastien Thurn in the free Udacity course AI for Robotics.  Basically he makes a circular array of the indexed weights using the mod operator `%`, sets a variable beta to 0, randomly chooses an index,
for loops through N where N is the number of indices and in the for loop firstly increments beta by the formula:

beta = beta + uniform sample from {0...2* Weight_max}

and then nested in the for loop, a while loop per below:

```
while w[index] < beta:
    beta = beta - w[index]
    index = index + 1

select p[index]
```

Then on to the next index to resample based on the probabilities (or normalized probability in the case presented in the course).

On Udacity find Lesson 8, video number 21 of Artificial Intelligence for Robotics where he is lecturing on particle filters.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how many times you want to sample the distribution.

Suppose you want to sample the distribution K times. Then, the time complexity using `np.random.choice()` each time is `O(K(n + log(n)))` when `n` is the number of items in the distribution.

In my case, I needed to sample the same distribution multiple times of the order of 10^3 where n is of the order of 10^6. I used the below code, which precomputes the cumulative distribution and samples it in `O(log(n))`. Overall time complexity is `O(n+K*log(n))`.

```
import numpy as np

n,k = 10**6,10**3

# Create dummy distribution
a = np.array([i+1 for i in range(n)])
p = np.array([1.0/n]*n)

cfd = p.cumsum()
for _ in range(k):
    x = np.random.uniform()
    idx = cfd.searchsorted(x, side='right')
    sampled_element = a[idx]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this, assuming we have weights at the same index as the elements in the element array.

```
import numpy as np
weights = [0.1, 0.3, 0.5] #weights for the item at index 0,1,2
# sum of weights should be <=1, you can also divide each weight by sum of all weights to standardise it to <=1 constraint.
trials = 1 #number of trials
num_item = 1 #number of items that can be picked in each trial
selected_item_arr = np.random.multinomial(num_item, weights, trials)
# gives number of times an item was selected at a particular index
# this assumes selection with replacement
# one possible output
# selected_item_arr
# array([[0, 0, 1]])
# say if trials = 5, the the possible output could be 
# selected_item_arr
# array([[1, 0, 0],
#   [0, 0, 1],
#   [0, 0, 1],
#   [0, 1, 0],
#   [0, 0, 1]])
```

Now let's assume, we have to sample out 3 items in 1 trial. You can assume that there are three balls R,G,B present in large quantity in ratio of their weights given by weight array, the following could be possible outcome:

```
num_item = 3
trials = 1
selected_item_arr = np.random.multinomial(num_item, weights, trials)
# selected_item_arr can give output like :
# array([[1, 0, 2]])
```

you can also think number of items to be selected as number of binomial/ multinomial trials within a set. So, the above example can be still work as

```
num_binomial_trial = 5
weights = [0.1,0.9] #say an unfair coin weights for H/T
num_experiment_set = 1
selected_item_arr = np.random.multinomial(num_binomial_trial, weights, num_experiment_set)
# possible output
# selected_item_arr
# array([[1, 4]])
# i.e H came 1 time and T came 4 times in 5 binomial trials. And one set contains 5 binomial trails.
```

Answer (score 1):

let's say you have

```
items = [11, 23, 43, 91] 
probability = [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1]
```

and you have function which generates a random number between [0, 1) (we can use random.random() here).
so now take the prefix sum of probability

```
prefix_probability=[0.2,0.5,0.9,1]
```

now we can just take a random number between 0-1 and use binary search to find where that number belongs in prefix_probability. that index will be your answer

Code will go something like this

```
return items[bisect.bisect(prefix_probability,random.random())]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to randomize on the total of all the weights and then use the values as the limit points for each var. Here is a crude implementation as a generator.

```
def rand_weighted(weights):
    """
    Generator which uses the weights to generate a
    weighted random values
    """
    sum_weights = sum(weights.values())
    cum_weights = {}
    current_weight = 0
    for key, value in sorted(weights.iteritems()):
        current_weight += value
        cum_weights[key] = current_weight
    while True:
        sel = int(random.uniform(0, 1) * sum_weights)
        for key, value in sorted(cum_weights.iteritems()):
            if sel < value:
                break
        yield key
```

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy

```
def choice(items, weights):
    return items[np.argmin((np.cumsum(weights) / sum(weights)) < np.random.rand())]
```

Comment: NumPy already has `np.random.choice`, as mentioned in the accepted answer that's been here since 2014. What's the point of rolling your own?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do something like this really fast really simple, from searching for ideas i finally built this template. The idea is receive the weighted values in a form of a json from the api, which here is simulated by the dict.

Then translate it into a list in which each value repeats proportionally to it's weight, and just use random.choice to select a value from the list.

I tried it running with 10, 100 and 1000 iterations. The distribution seems pretty solid.

```
def weighted_choice(weighted_dict):
    """Input example: dict(apples=60, oranges=30, pineapples=10)"""
    weight_list = []
    for key in weighted_dict.keys():
        weight_list += [key] * weighted_dict[key]
    return random.choice(weight_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't love the syntax of any of those. I really wanted to just specify what the items were and what the weighting of each was. I realize I could have used `random.choices` but instead I quickly wrote the class below.

```
import random, string
from numpy import cumsum

class randomChoiceWithProportions:
    '''
    Accepts a dictionary of choices as keys and weights as values. Example if you want a unfair dice:


    choiceWeightDic = {"1":0.16666666666666666, "2": 0.16666666666666666, "3": 0.16666666666666666
    , "4": 0.16666666666666666, "5": .06666666666666666, "6": 0.26666666666666666}
    dice = randomChoiceWithProportions(choiceWeightDic)

    samples = []
    for i in range(100000):
        samples.append(dice.sample())

    # Should be close to .26666
    samples.count("6")/len(samples)

    # Should be close to .16666
    samples.count("1")/len(samples)
    '''
    def __init__(self, choiceWeightDic):
        self.choiceWeightDic = choiceWeightDic
        weightSum = sum(self.choiceWeightDic.values())
        assert weightSum == 1, 'Weights sum to ' + str(weightSum) + ', not 1.'
        self.valWeightDict = self._compute_valWeights()

    def _compute_valWeights(self):
        valWeights = list(cumsum(list(self.choiceWeightDic.values())))
        valWeightDict = dict(zip(list(self.choiceWeightDic.keys()), valWeights))
        return valWeightDict

    def sample(self):
        num = random.uniform(0,1)
        for key, val in self.valWeightDict.items():
            if val >= num:
                return key
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide random.choice() with a pre-weighted list:

**Solution & Test:**

```
import random

options = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
weights = [1, 2, 5, 2]

weighted_options = [[opt]*wgt for opt, wgt in zip(options, weights)]
weighted_options = [opt for sublist in weighted_options for opt in sublist]
print(weighted_options)

# test

counts = {c: 0 for c in options}
for x in range(10000):
    counts[random.choice(weighted_options)] += 1

for opt, wgt in zip(options, weights):
    wgt_r = counts[opt] / 10000 * sum(weights)
    print(opt, counts[opt], wgt, wgt_r)
```

**Output:**

```
['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd']
a 1025 1 1.025
b 1948 2 1.948
c 5019 5 5.019
d 2008 2 2.008
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't define in advance how many items you want to pick (so, you don't do something like `k=10`) and you just have probabilities, you can do the below. Note that your probabilities do not need to add up to 1, they can be independent of each other:

```
soup_items = ['pepper', 'onion', 'tomato', 'celery'] 
items_probability = [0.2, 0.3, 0.9, 0.1]

selected_items = [item for item,p in zip(soup_items,items_probability) if random.random()<p]
print(selected_items)
>>>['pepper','tomato']
```

Answer (score -1):

**Step-1:** Generate CDF `F` in which you're interesting

**Step-2:** Generate u.r.v. `u`

**Step-3:** Evaluate `z=F^{-1}(u)`

This modeling is described in course of probability theory or stochastic processes. This is applicable just because you have easy CDF.