# Given a dictionary of weights that sum to 1 - how to use random to select a weighted key

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that looks like this.

```
mychoice = {0.7: 2, 0.2: 1, 0.1:3}
```

I will use the following to select which value to use.  In the above, value 2 will be selected 70% of the time and value 1 will be selected 20% of the time and 3, 10% of the time.

What is the best method to use the following to generate a random number between  0 and 1 and to select randomly the value to use?

```
from random import random
ran = random()
if ran>.10 and <.30 then select value 1 with a key of .20
```

Thanks

Comment: A dictionary isn't an appropriate data structure for this because it prevents you from assigning the same probability to two values.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I'd say a dict is okay, but the "weights" should be **values**, not **keys**. Anyway, good point.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/3679694/222914 with a good answer in http://stackoverflow.com/a/4322940/222914

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking your example, with some modifications (swap key/value in the dict):

```
mychoice = {1: 0.2, 2: 0.7, 3:0.1}
current = 0
limits = {}

for key in mychoice:
    limits[key] = (current,current + mychoice[key])
    current = current + mychoice[key] #Next range should start at the end of current

#This should give a new dictionary: {1:(0,0.2),2:(0.2,0.9),3;(0.9,1)}

r = random.random() # float between 0 and 1

for key in limits:
    range = limits[key]
    if r >= range[0] and r < range[1]:
          return key
return None
```

This can be optimized, but you get the idea.

Comment: This is the essence of a basic biased roulette wheel. Kudos (+1)

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that comes to my mind: sort them and add them up.

Let's assume you've followed my advice and changed the structure of your dict like this:

```
mychoice = {2: 0.7, 1: 0.2, 3: 0.1}
```

Let's build a dict with accumulated weights:

```
temp = sorted(((v, w) for v, w in mychoice.items()), key = lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)
accum = [(val[0], sum(_[1] for _ in temp[:i+1])) for i, val in enumerate(temp)]
```

(that's a little messy, can someone optimize?)

Anyway, now you have `accum` as `[(2, 0.7), (1, 0.9), (3, 1)]`

So:

```
r = random.random()

for vw in accum:
    if vw[1] > r:
        print vw[0]
        break
```

**EDIT:** As astynax cleverly points out, there's no need to sort the weights, as the list of accumulated probabilities will be sorted anyway.

So we only need:

```
accum = ((k, sum(mychoice.values()[:i]))
    for i, k in enumerate(mychoice.keys(), 1))
```

And then generate a random value and get the result the same way as before.

Comment: I probably should have looked at the link Janne Karila posted in the [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868839/given-a-dictionary-of-weights-that-sum-to-1-how-to-use-random-to-select-a-weig#comment14161298_10868839). It's essentially the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> d = {0.7: 2, 0.2: 1, 0.1:3}
>>> keys = [[k] * int(round(10*k)) for k in d.keys()]
>>> keys
[[0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7], [0.1], [0.2, 0.2]]
>>> import itertools
>>> keys = list(itertools.chain(*keys))
[0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2]
>>> import random
>>> d[random.choice(keys)]
2
>>> d[random.choice(keys)]
2
>>> d[random.choice(keys)]
3
```

Alternative: To express probability of selection to a resolution of, say, 1 in a 1000:

```
>>> keys = [[k] * int(round(1000*k)) for k in d.keys()]
```

Comment: What if the weights are like `0.8660254037844386`?

Comment: Perhaps a better approach would be a biased roulette wheel is what the OP needs. I will post the code for that soon

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice way to do it using [`numpys digitize`](http://scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List_With_Doc#digitize) and `accumulate`:

```
from random import random
import numpy as np

mychoice = {0.7: 2, 0.2: 1, 0.1: 3}

bins = np.add.accumulate(mychoice.keys())
for i in xrange(100):
    print mychoice.values()[np.digitize([random()], bins)[0]],

#Output:
1 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 3 2 2 3 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 2
1 2 2 2 2 3 3 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 3 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
3 2 1 2 2 2 3 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 1
```

As `@Karl Knechtel` points out a `dict` is not a suitable structure for doing this as you can't have repeated weights, but we'll use this as a starting point regardless. How to do it:

1. First create bins using `accumulate` (using bins allows you to use repeated weights).
2. Then we use `digitize` to see which bins random numbers fall into, and use this index for `mychoice.values()` (although `mychoice` is a dict the keys and values retain their order provided there are no insertions or deletions..).

Answer (score 0):

With `d = {2: 0.7, 1: 0.2, 3: 0.1}` which is more logical (different choices and their respective weights, which can repeat), you can use this `random_weighter` function, which accepts also weights that do not sum to `1.0`.

```
import random

def random_weighted(d):
    r = random.random() * sum(d.itervalues())
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        r = r - v
        if r <= 0.:
            return k 

d = {2: 0.7, 1: 0.2, 3: 0.1}
for i in xrange(10):
    print random_weighted(d),
```

prints (for example):

```
3 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 2
```