# How to use NLTK to generate sentences from an induced grammar?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I have a (large) list of parsed sentences (which were parsed using the Stanford parser), for example, the sentence "Now you can be entertained" has the following tree:

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (ADVP (RB Now))
    (, ,)
    (NP (PRP you))
    (VP (MD can)
      (VP (VB be)
        (VP (VBN entertained))))
    (. .)))
```

I am using the set of sentence trees to induce a grammar using nltk:

```
import nltk

# ... for each sentence tree t, add its production to allProductions
allProductions += t.productions()

# Induce the grammar
S = nltk.Nonterminal('S')
grammar = nltk.induce_pcfg(S, allProductions)
```

Now I would like to use `grammar` to generate new, random sentences. My hope is that since the grammar was learned from a specific set of input examples, then the generated sentences will be semantically similar. Can I do this in nltk?

If I can't use nltk to do this, do any other tools exist that can take the (possibly reformatted) `grammar` and generate sentences?

Comment: In same spot, please check out this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39061349/paraphrasing-using-nltk

Answer (score 14):

In NLTK 2.0 you can use `nltk.parse.generate` to generate *all* possible [sentences for a given grammar](http://nltk.org/_modules/nltk/parse/generate.html).

This code defines a function which should generate a single sentence based on the production rules in a (P)CFG.

```
# This example uses choice to choose from possible expansions
from random import choice
# This function is based on _generate_all() in nltk.parse.generate
# It therefore assumes the same import environment otherwise.
def generate_sample(grammar, items=["S"]):
    frags = []
    if len(items) == 1:
        if isinstance(items[0], Nonterminal):
            for prod in grammar.productions(lhs=items[0]):
                frags.append(generate_sample(grammar, prod.rhs()))
        else:
            frags.append(items[0])
    else:
        # This is where we need to make our changes
        chosen_expansion = choice(items)
        frags.append(generate_sample,chosen_expansion)
    return frags
```

To make use of the weights in your PCFG, you'll obviously want to use a better sampling method than `choice()`, which implicitly assumes all expansions of the current node are equiprobable.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, if you generate random sentences, they may be semantically correct, but they will probably lose their sense.

*(It sounds to me a bit like those MIT students did with their [SCIgen program](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/scigen/) which is auto-generating scientific paper. Very interesting btw.)*

Anyway, I never did it myself, but it seems possible with nltk.bigrams, you may way to [have a look there](http://nltk.org/book/ch02.html) under **Generating Random Text with Bigrams**.

You can also [generate all subtrees of a current tree](http://nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tree.html#Tree.subtrees), I'm not sure if it is what you want either.

Answer (score 3):

My solution to generate a random sentence from an existing nltk.CFG grammar:

```
def generate_sample(grammar, prod, frags):        
    if prod in grammar._lhs_index: # Derivation
        derivations = grammar._lhs_index[prod]            
        derivation = random.choice(derivations)            
        for d in derivation._rhs:            
            generate_sample(grammar, d, frags)
    elif prod in grammar._rhs_index:
        # terminal
        frags.append(str(prod))
```

And now it can be used:

```
frags = []  
generate_sample(grammar, grammar.start(), frags)
print( ' '.join(frags) )
```

Comment: The line `generate_sample(d, frags)` should read `generate_sample(grammar, d, frags)`.

Answer (score 2):

With an nltk [Text](http://nltk.org/_modules/nltk/text.html) object you can call 'generate()' on it which will "Print random text, generated using a trigram language model."http://nltk.org/_modules/nltk/text.html

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: here is a working link: https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.text.html#nltk.text.Text.generate

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by the above, here's one which uses iteration instead of recursion.

```
import random

def rewrite_at(index, replacements, the_list):
    del the_list[index]
    the_list[index:index] = replacements

def generate_sentence(grammar):
    sentence_list = [grammar.start()]
    all_terminals = False
    while not all_terminals:
        all_terminals = True
        for position, symbol in enumerate(sentence_list):
            if symbol in grammar._lhs_index:
                all_terminals = False
                derivations = grammar._lhs_index[symbol]
                derivation = random.choice(derivations) # or weighted_choice(derivations) if you have a function for that
                rewrite_at(position, derivation.rhs(), sentence_list)
    return sentence_list
```

Or if you want the tree of the derivation, this one.

```
from nltk.tree import Tree

def tree_from_production(production):
    return Tree(production.lhs(), production.rhs())

def leaf_positions(the_tree):
    return [the_tree.leaf_treeposition(i) for i in range(len(the_tree.leaves()))]

def generate_tree(grammar):
    initial_derivations = grammar._lhs_index[grammar.start()]
    initial_derivation = random.choice(initial_derivations) # or weighed_choice if you have that function
    running_tree = tree_from_production(initial_derivation)
    all_terminals = False
    while not all_terminals:
        all_terminals = True
        for position in leaf_positions(running_tree):
            node_label = running_tree[position]
            if node_label in grammar._lhs_index:
                all_terminals = False
                derivations = grammar._lhs_index[node_label]
                derivation = random.choice(derivations) # or weighed_choice if you have that function
                running_tree[position] = tree_from_production(derivation)
    return running_tree
```

Here's a weighted_choice function for NLTK PCFG production rules to use with the above, adapted from Ned Batchelder's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679694/a-weighted-version-of-random-choice) for weighted choice functions in general:

```
def weighted_choice(productions):
    prods_with_probs = [(prod, prod.prob()) for prod in productions]
    total = sum(prob for prod, prob in prods_with_probs)
    r = random.uniform(0, total)
    upto = 0
    for prod, prob in prods_with_probs:
        if upto + prob >= r:
            return prod
        upto += prob
    assert False, "Shouldn't get here"
```