# Generating Sentences *Randomly* Given a CFG

Tags: python, random, context-free-grammar

I want to generate sentences **randomly** from a given context-free grammar.

Randomly is the important part because my grammar is quite large, and [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/howto/generate.html) generates all the possible utterances which falls short on recursions (i.e. `E -> A E`) and takes too long to generate "interesting" utterances in short time (interesting being unlike the other utterances preceding the current one).

Are there any Python libraries for that? Thanks!

Comment: How does your CFG look like; i.e. what type is it?

Comment: @L3viathan It's in EBNF.

Comment: And all possible expansions are equally likely; you don't have a PCFG?

Comment: It's a CFG for a programming language, so yes they are all equally likely (or can be assumed so).

Comment: Ah, I was confused by your mention of NLTK, then. I'm not aware of any such libraries then; just parse your grammar into a dictionary and iteratively expand a list starting with `["start"]`, until no more expansions are possible.

Comment: If your grammar describes an infinite language, not all strings can really be equally likely, right?

Answer (score 0):

NLTK doesn't provide a method to generate random sentences from a grammar, although as indicated in this related SO question, [How to use NLTK to generate sentences from an induced grammar?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15009656), it can generate random sentences from trigrams.

If you want to write your own Python function, you might be interested in this 1997 paper by Bruce Mackenzie, [Generating Strings at Random from a Context Free Grammar](http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/research/reports/TechReps/1997/tr_9710.pdf). (I found the link in [this answer to a different SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/274047).) The algorithm involves precomputing weights in an O(N<sup>2</sup>) preprocessing step, and requires that the grammar have no epsilon productions (productions that expand to the empty string).

Comment: "NLTK doesn't provide a method to generate random sentences from a grammar" See [Generating sentences from context-free grammars - nltk.org](http://www.nltk.org/howto/generate.html)

Comment: @bora: generating *all* sentences and generating *random* sentences are different problems. You yourself emphasize that in your question.

Comment: Oh you meant it that way. Yes sure, my bad!