# use dictionary as a list in python

Tags: python

I have a dictionary with name dic in python, where the keys are strings and the corresponding values are integers.

```
dic ={ 'a' : 2, 'b' : 3, 'c':4, 'd':5 }.
```

Note that `2+3+4+5=14`.

Now I need to impose an order to this dictionary, say the order is from `'a'`, to `'b'`, and then to `'c'`.  Then, I randomly generate 3 numbers from the list of intergers from 1 to 14, say, `2`, `9`, and `10`. Then, these 3 numbers would correspond to the keys `'a'`, `'c'`, and `'d'`.

All I can think of is to use `dic.keys` and `dic.values` to create two corresponding lists and then calculate the presums and do it in a very trivial way.

Is there a default python function to do this?

Comment: Please show us what you have got so far.

Comment: Why would `2`, `9`, and `10` correspond to `'a'`, `'c'`, and `'d'`? Was that arbitrarily chosen?

Comment: are you trying to randomly sample the keys with the given probabilities `(n/sum(...))`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: they happen to match to the cumulative sum of the values for those keys.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to make a [weighted random choice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679694/a-weighted-version-of-random-choice), with the keys being the available choices and the values the weights..

Comment: No. Of course not. Imagine 'a' repeat for 2 times, 'b' repeats for 3 times, 'c' repeats for 4 times and 'd' repeats for 5 times. Now, put all these 4 types of strings in a box, and do a random sample of it. And I want to know how many differnt types of strings you have got. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Martijin, yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can consider using [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) like so.

```
>>> import random
>>> p = 2*['a'] + 3*['b'] + 4*['c'] + 5*['d']
>>> random.sample(p, 3)
['b', 'b', 'a']
```

From the docs, `random.sample` *returns a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence or set*. It is *used for random sampling without replacement*. Therefore, the largest sample you can  get from a population of size 14 is size 14, and a sample of size 14 is guaranteed to be a permutation of `p`.

Alternatively you can use your method of selecting an integer between 1 and 14 inclusive to make weighted random choices using `p` like this:

```
>>> k = random.choice(range(1, 15))
>>> p[k-1]
'b'
```

or, if you don't need the "index" of the selected element:

```
>>> random.choice(p)
'c'
```

However, note that by using `random.choice` repeatedly, you will be sampling *with* replacement (unless you have some mechanism of removing selecting elements from the population). This may be what you want though.

To construct your population `p` dynamically using your dictionary, you can do something like this:

```
>>> sum((w*[k] for k, w in dic.items()), [])
['d', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'b']
```

Note that the letters will not necessarily be in order as shown above! But anyways, you can sort them easily using Python's built in `sorted` function.

```
>>> sum(sorted(w*[k] for k, w in dic.items()), [])
['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd']
```