# How to use a range for dict keys?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, key

I have a program that scans Google for links, it verifies how many links you've found and then tries to find a success right for your search:

```
def check_urls_for_queries(self):
    """ The returned URLS will be run through a query regex to see if
        they have a query parameter.
          http://google.com <- False
          http://example.com/php?id=2 <- True
    """
    filename = settings.create_random_filename()
    print("File being saved to: {}".format(filename))
    with open("{}\\{}.txt".format(settings.DORK_SCAN_RESULTS_PATH, filename),
              "a+") as results:
        for url in self.connect_to_search_engine():
            match = settings.QUERY_REGEX.match(url) # Match by regex for anything
                                                    # that has a ?=<PARAM> in it
            if match:
                results.write(url + "\n")
    amount_of_urls = len(open(settings.DORK_SCAN_RESULTS_PATH + "\\" + filename
                              + ".txt", 'r').readlines())
    return("\nFound a total of {} usable links with query (GET) parameters, urls"
           " have been saved to {}\\{}.txt. This Dork has a success rate of {}%".
           format(amount_of_urls, settings.DORK_SCAN_RESULTS_PATH, filename,
                  self.success_rate[amount_of_urls]
                    if amount_of_urls in self.success_rate.keys() else
                  'Unknown success rate'))
```

What I would like to do is create the success rate using a range per dict key:

```
success_rate = {
    range(1, 10): 10, range(11, 20): 20, range(21, 30): 30,
    range(31, 40): 40, range(41, 50): 50, range(51, 60): 60,
    range(61, 70): 70, range(71, 80): 80, range(81, 90): 90,
    range(91, 100): 100
}
```

However obviously this doesn't work because lists are not hashable objects:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tool.py", line 2, in <module>
    from lib.core import BANNER
  File "C:\Users\Documents\bin\python\pybelt\lib\core\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from dork_check import DorkScanner
  File "C:\Users\Documents\bin\python\pybelt\lib\core\dork_check\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from dorks import DorkScanner
  File "C:\Users\\Documents\bin\python\pybelt\lib\core\dork_check\dorks.py", line 6, in <module>
    class DorkScanner(object):
  File "C:\Users\Documents\bin\python\pybelt\lib\core\dork_check\dorks.py", line 11, in DorkScanner
    range(1, 10): 10, range(11, 20): 20, range(21, 30): 30,
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Is there a way I could use a range for a dict key to save myself from having to make a key from 1 – 100?

Comment: Make them tuples.  tuples are hashable.  `tuple(range(1, 10))`

Comment: You wouldn't want to use lists here, no, because they contain *all integers in the range*. Use `xrange()` objects  instead, these are hashable, and only store the start and end values.

Comment: it seems you are rounding up to the nearest "10th" why not just do that instead of a look up

Comment: @PatrickHaugh: why? That'd be just as much a waste.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I'll give that a try, thank you

Comment: @MooingRawr you're so right. The entry is not a range but a number within this range. So do `((i // 10) + 1) * 10` and you're done.

Comment: @MooingRawr How would you propose that I do so?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre man why you summing things up faster than me. I guess that's why you have the 26k and I have 1k ;3

Comment: @MooingRawr that one never gets old :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`range()` in Python 2 is merely a function that returns a list of integers, it is not itself a type of object. And you wouldn't want to use lists here, no, because they contain *all integers in the range*.

You could use [`xrange()` objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) instead, these are hashable, and only store the start and end values. However, unless you plan to use *other* `xrange()` objects to test these keys, a dictionary with such keys is not very useful, you'd have to loop over the dictionary to test your rate against each `xrange` object manually.

Your success rate dictionary could more simply be replaced by maths; just round your numbers up to the nearest multiple of 10 (simply using floor division):

```
success_rate = ((amount_of_urls // 10) + 1) * 10
```

Do test if that resulting value is between 10 and 100:

```
10 <= success_rate <= 100
```

Answer (score 2):

RangeKeyDict class could be able to handle cases like this, which is more general and easy to use. For usage, check the codes in __main__

to install it using:

```
pip install range-key-dict
```

Usage:

```
from range_key_dict import RangeKeyDict

if __name__ == '__main__':
    range_key_dict = RangeKeyDict({
        (0, 100): 'A',
        (100, 200): 'B',
        (200, 300): 'C',
    })

    # test normal case
    assert range_key_dict[70] == 'A'
    assert range_key_dict[170] == 'B'
    assert range_key_dict[270] == 'C'

    # test case when the number is float
    assert range_key_dict[70.5] == 'A'

    # test case not in the range, with default value
    assert range_key_dict.get(1000, 'D') == 'D'
```

https://github.com/albertmenglongli/range-key-dict

Reference: Please check the answer in this post: [Range as dictionary key in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39358092/range-as-dictionary-key-in-python/45063158#45063158)