# Can you use a variable in switch-case in python?

Tags: python, switch-statement

Can I use this method in coding on python 3 ?

```
def switch_demo(argument):

    switcher = {
        51>switcher>13: "January",
        2: "February",
        3: "March",
        4: "April",
        5: "May",
        6: "June",
        7: "July",
        8: "August",
        9: "September",
        10: "October",
        11: "November",
        90>switcher>52: "December"
    }

print switcher.get(argument, "Invalid month")
```

My question is this:

I want to get range of number and return code.

Comment: How do you intend to call switch_demo() and what will you do with the return value?

Comment: i need to call function and inter value of range for example call  switch_demo(15) and then return "January"

Comment: Did you mean call switch_demo(1) and return “January”?

Comment: No i want to call call switch_demo("range of between 13 to 51") then return “January”

Comment: you can't use it. Use `if/elif/else`. For values smaller then `13` it can return value from dictionary.

Comment: thanks but i need the method for this method . but writing this method question with if_elif_else is very complex and confuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are talking about two different things: Some out of range values and then the in range values of 1-12:

```
def switch_demo(argument):
    switcher = {
        1: "January",
        2: "February",
        3: "March",
        4: "April",
        5: "May",
        6: "June",
        7: "July",
        8: "August",
        9: "September",
        10: "October",
        11: "November",
        12: "December"
    }
    return switcher.get(argument, "Invalid month")

def switch_range(argument):
    if argument <= 12:
        return switch_demo(argument)
    elif argument <= 51:
        return switch_demo(1)
    else:
        return switch_demo(12)
```

Comment: i have code generator that generate random key between 1 to 600 and i decision 600/12 so this return number , one of above month. 13-51 return "January" , 52-90 return "December" and so on.

Comment: Why not random//50?

Answer (score 1):

Got answer from [Range as dictionary key in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39358092/range-as-dictionary-key-in-python)

Try this if you want a range of values as keys for a dictionary

```
switcher = dict(
                [(n, 'January')
                    for n in range(13,51)] +
                [(2, 'February')] +
                [(3, 'March')] +
                [(4, 'April')] +
                [(5, 'May')] +
                [(6, 'June')] +
                [(7, 'July')] +
                [(8, 'August')] +
                [(9, 'September')] +
                [(10, 'October')] +
                [(11, 'November')] +
                [(n, 'December') 
                    for n in range(52,90)]
                )
```