# How to create a rating user django

Tags: django, django-views

I have a mini blog and user profiles. On the user profiles page, I display information:

```
Comments count of this user; 
Posts count of this user;
```

I display the number of comments in the template userprofile like this:

```
{{user.comments.count}}
```

I would like to make a small rating system, for example:

If a user has left 10 comments and 10 posts - he is a cat (cat- word).
If 20 is a dog (dog - word).
30 - elephant, etc.

For this I would like to have a separate table in the database, so that I can then make a selection by users rating.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this post:
[Range as dictionary key in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39358092/range-as-dictionary-key-in-python)

Creating a seperate `model` and assigning user `titles` as a relation would lead to way to many database transitions, here you can just grab the value of user `posts` with `count` and then use a custom made dictionary with `range` object as a key to assign he correct `title`

**Update**

To implement you would do something like this:

```
def user(request, pk):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    count_of_posts = user.posts.count()
    titles = {
        range(1, 10): 'Cat',
        range(10, 20): 'Dog',
        range(20, 30): 'Elephant'
        # add more titles
    }
    user_title = ''
    for key in titles:
        if count_of_posts in key:
            user_title = titles[key]
    return render(request, 'user.html', {'user': user,
                                         'user_title': user_title})
```

**Update 2**

Well since you want to add tags to a user list there isn't really a way around it except creating a seperate field for it in a `User` model and updating it with the information everytime a `user` creates or deletes a `post`, here's how I see it working:

*1.Add a **title** field to your User model.*

**models.py**

```
class User(models.Model): # your user model with your inheritance, disregard the 'models.Model' part, its just an example
    # your User model fields
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=50)
```

*2. In your **views** when you **create** (or **delete**) a **post**, check the current users posts **count** and if the value changed assign the new **title** and **save** it.*

**views.py**

```
titles = { # add this dictionary seperately in your views file
    range(1, 10): 'Cat',
    range(10, 20): 'Dog',
    range(20, 30): 'Elephant'
    # add more titles
}

def index(request): # the view that handles post creation 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST) # your post form class
        if form.is_valid():
            new_post = form.save(commit=False)
            new_post.user = request.user
            new_post.save()
            count_of_posts = request.user.posts.count()

            for key in titles: # assign a title to the user and save it
                if count_of_posts in key:
                    if request.user.title != titles[key]:
                        request.user.title = titles[key]
                        request.user.save()
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})


 def delete_post(request):
     # create a similar check but call it when deleting a post


 def user_list(request): #template below
     users = User.objects.all()
     return render(request, 'user_list.html', {'users', users})


 def user(request, pk): # template below
     user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
     return render(request, 'user.html', {'user': user})
```

*3. Create your **templates**.*

**user_list.html**

```
{% for user in users %}
    {{ user }} is a {{ user.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

**user.html**

```
{{ user }} is a {{ user.title }}
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, would be very grateful if you could help me with the syntax

Comment: check out the updated version, this should work

Comment: Thanks a lot, can you please tell me how I can display this in the template? (tag) and how can I display a list of users by rating on a separate page?

Comment: I've updated my answer, check the `Update 2` section :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! As soon as I get to the computer, I will definitely try to implement it according to your example.

Comment: let me know if you have any issues :)

Comment: Can you please tell me how to link the rating not to posts, but to comments count? As a commentary, I use django-comments-xtd https://github.com/danirus/django-comments-xtd/tree/master/django_comments_xtd

Comment: use the same logic we did with posts: when a comment gets submitted update a field on you `User` model from a dictionary with `range` object keys