# How to access both range and strings in the same dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I have a dictionary with following

```
check = RangeDict({{
range(10, 100): 40,
range(110, 115): 40,
range(118, 121): 50,
range(130, 131): 50,
range(140, 141): 30
}
```

and I access the value with the following

```
class RangeDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if not isinstance(item, range):  
            for key in self:
                if item in key:
                    return self[key]
            raise KeyError(item)
        else:
             return super().__getitem__(item)  

id =  199
print(check[id])
```

I need my dictionary to also include

```
{
range(10, 100): 40,
range(110, 115): 40,
range(118, 121): 50,
range(130, 131): 50,
range(140, 141): 30,
"a100": 110,
"c120": 100
}
```

Is this possible if using range for the integers and to also include string: values and how can I change function to read string

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Comment: The keys of a dictionary do not all have to be the same type.

Comment: How can I return the string value if the key does not include range?

Comment: Can you perhaps clarify what you are trying to do? The point of dictionaries is *direct* access to keys/values. Scanning through all keys to find which one matches the ``item`` defeats that point.

Comment: "I access the value with the following" The code as shown is unsuitable to return anything. Once the loop has picked an appropriate ``key`` ``range``, the ``return self[key]`` will recurse and hit the bogus ``return RangeDict.values()``. Even fixing this to ``return self.values()`` or similar just returns *all* values for *all* keys. Can you please [edit] your question to show code that is feasible for what you claim it does, and reproduces the error you get later on? The [mre] help page should be useful.

Comment: You should use `UserDict` for subclassing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390827/how-to-properly-subclass-dict-and-override-getitem-setitem

Comment: I think things will be much simpler if you keep your dictionary keys as simple strings -- can you show/explain why you must use a range as a key?  Just because dictionary keys _can_ be any immutable data type, that doesn't mean it's a good idea, especially if a simpler alternative would work.

Comment: I think OP is working from this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39358140/14536215

Comment: The range of keys go up to the 80000's so not sure sure what other approach I can use plus it also includes strings eg.a22200

Comment: Test ``if isinstance(item, int):`` instead of ``if not isinstance(item, range):``.

Comment: That works thank you. Would people think there is a better apporach to this. The concern is there is a huge range of numbers to be included.

Comment: If the ``range``s are not overlapping and may be sorted (i.e. you don't need insertion order), you can have a *much* better lookup speed by using binary search or a trie. But how best to do that is rather hard to say from such a small example.

Answer (score -1):

Just,

```
check = {
range(10, 100): 40,
range(110, 115): 40,
range(118, 121): 50,
range(130, 131): 50,
range(140, 141): 30,
"a100": 110,
"c120": 100
}
```

This is stored as :

```
{range(10, 100): 40,
 range(110, 115): 40,
 range(118, 121): 50,
 range(130, 131): 50,
 range(140, 141): 30,
 'a100': 110,
 'c120': 100}
```

And then to access,

```
a = check[range(10,100)]
```

Which gives:

```
40
```

Comment: This won't work for the desired in-range access, such as ``check[113]`` evaluating to ``40`` because ``113`` is in ``range(110, 115)``.

Comment: Well, if you just want to add range, just do it with a for loop. Like:                    for i in range(10, 100):
    check[i] = 40. Next time be more clear with your problems.