# Creating probability by value from a dict

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I'm creating a type of *survival game* in python, and am creating the different animals you can encounter and *"battle"* with (users will only encounter one animal at a time). I want certain animals with a lower number associated with them to have a higher probability of showing up then the animals with a higher number associated to them:

```
POSSIBLE_ANIMALS_ENCOUNTERED = {
    "deer": 50,        "elk": 75,           "mountain lion": 150,
    "rat": 5,          "raccoon": 15,       "squirrel": 5,
    "black bear": 120, "grizzly bear": 200, "snake": 5,
}
```

So, I would like a `rat` to appear more then a `deer` and just as much as a `squirrel` or `snake`. How can I go about creating probability for the animals inside of the `dict` based on their value? I'd like it so that the user will see a higher percentage of animals with lower value, and a lower percentage of animals with a higher value.

For example:

The user should see a animal with a value from 1 to 5, 50% of the time (0.5), an animal with a value from 6 to 50 %25 percent of the time (0.25), and any animal with a value higher then that 10 percent of the time (0.10).

Comment: How exactly do the numbers compare? Will someone see 10 times more rats than deer? 3 times more squirrels than raccoons?

Comment: @glibdud see edits, hopefully that will explain it better

Comment: Wait, so if you want anything in a range 6-50 to be encountered 25% of the time, why not just set them to 0.25?

Comment: @tristan The numbers they are associated with will be their HP, I guess I could probably put the value into a tuple with hp and percentage?

Comment: So multiple animals can be encountered at once?

Comment: @glibdud I'd love that, but that's a little to much for me to handle at this point, so no, they will only be able to encounter one animal at a time.

Comment: Then I still don't understand the numbers. Maybe it would be easier to understand if you showed what you've tried so far?

Comment: Ah, I understand what you're looking to do, even if you're making it harder than you really need to for yourself.  There's a couple subproblems in here, so it will take me a second to write up an answer using only the standard lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to codify the percentage likelihood of an encounter based on "health points" (`encounter_ranges` tuples are from the data in your edit), then do a weighted random choice from your elements.  I've put comments inline:

```
from random import random
from bisect import bisect

POSSIBLE_ANIMALS_ENCOUNTERED = {
    "deer": 50,        "elk": 75,           "mountain lion": 150,
    "rat": 5,          "raccoon": 15,       "squirrel": 5,
    "black bear": 120, "grizzly bear": 200, "snake": 5,
}

# codify your ranges.  (min, max, encounter %) 
encounter_ranges = (
    (50, float('inf'), .10),
    (6, 50, .25),
    (1, 5, .50)
)

# create a list of their probability to be encountered
# replace .items() with .iteritems() if python 2.x
ANIMAL_ENCOUNTER_PERCENTAGE_PER_HP_LIST = []
for k, v in POSSIBLE_ANIMALS_ENCOUNTERED.items():
    for encounter_chance in encounter_ranges:
        if (v >= encounter_chance[0]) and (v <= encounter_chance[1]):
            # multiplied by 100 because we're going to use it in a weighted random below
            ANIMAL_ENCOUNTER_PERCENTAGE_PER_HP_LIST.append([k, encounter_chance[2] * 100])


# With our percentages in hand, we need to do a weighted random distribution
# if you're only planning on encountering one animal at a time.
# stolen from http://stackoverflow.com/a/4322940/559633
def weighted_choice(choices):
    values, weights = zip(*choices)
    total = 0
    cum_weights = []
    for w in weights:
        total += w
        cum_weights.append(total)
    x = random() * total
    i = bisect(cum_weights, x)
    return values[i]

# run this function to return the animal you will encounter:
weighted_choice(ANIMAL_ENCOUNTER_PERCENTAGE_PER_HP_LIST)
```

Note that this approach will always return *something* -- a 100% chance encounter of *some animal*.  If you want to make the encounters more random, that's a much simpler problem, but I didn't include it as you'd need to specify how you expect this game mechanic to work (random 0-100% chance of any encounter?  a percentage chance of the encounter based on the return (50% chance of encounter if rat is returned)? etc).

Note that I wrote this for Python 3, as if you're new to Python, you really should be using 3.x, but I left a comment in what you need to switch if you decide to stick with 2.x.

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you!