# How to make an array of events reflect the real-life probabilities of those events without repeating them?

Tags: python, arrays, random

So if the array I made to simulate picking a coloured ball from a bag looked like this:

```
A = ["Blue", "Green", "Yellow"]
```

then I could just use the

```
random.choice()
```

function to simulate picking one from the bag. But if I had a different amount of coloured balls in the bag (say 3 green, 5 blue and 10 yellow), how could I make the random choice from the array reflect the different probabilities of picking each colour?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please show the code that you have tried and the issues that you have with it.

Comment: This is trivial to research. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/3679694/3001761 (or just actually put 18 entries in the list...)

Comment: "say 3 green, 5 blue and 10 yellow" so `['green']*3 + ['blue']*5 + ['yellow']*10` are all the balls in your bag and then you want to make a choice of those? hmmm...

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the link. Could you explain how the code works and, if possible, how it can be adapted to other situations?

Comment: No, that would be too broad for a question, let alone comments!

Answer (score 2):

Simple, you put the ball in the bag many times

```
b = "Blue"
g = "Green"
y = "Yellow"
A = []

def append_balls(list, color, quantity):
    for i in range(quantity):
        list.append(color)

append_balls(A, b, 5)
append_balls(A, g, 3)
append_balls(A, y, 10)

print(A)
# A = ['Blue', 'Blue', 'Blue', 'Blue', 'Blue', 'Green', 
#      'Green', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Yellow', 'Yellow', 'Yellow',
#      'Yellow', 'Yellow', 'Yellow', 'Yellow', 'Yellow', 'Yellow']
```

Now you can use `random.choice(A)` to select a random ball from the bag.

Comment: why are you appending `quantity`? don't you want to `append(color)`?