# Weighted random numbers in Python from a list of values

Tags: python, list, numpy, random, scipy

I am trying to create a list of 10,000 random numbers between 1 and 1000. But I want 80-85% of the numbers to be the same category( I mean some 100 numbers out of these should appear 80% of the times in the list of random numbers) and the rest appear around 15-20% of the times. Any idea if this can be done in Python/NumPy/SciPy. Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are these 100 numbers placed consecutively?

Comment: No. They can be spread out anyway but should be between 1 and 1000.

Comment: Why do you need a special function then? Just use `random.randint()` 2 times. First time to select those 100 vs rest and next time to choose among them

Comment: How are the numbers categorized?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A weighted version of random.choice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679694/a-weighted-version-of-random-choice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach -

```
a = np.arange(1,1001) # Input array to extract numbers from

# Select 100 random unique numbers from input array and get also store leftovers
p1 = np.random.choice(a,size=100,replace=0)
p2 = np.setdiff1d(a,p1)

# Get random indices for indexing into p1 and p2
p1_idx = np.random.randint(0,p1.size,(8000))
p2_idx = np.random.randint(0,p2.size,(2000))

# Index and concatenate and randomize their positions
out = np.random.permutation(np.hstack((p1[p1_idx], p2[p2_idx])))
```

Let's verify after run -

```
In [78]: np.in1d(out, p1).sum()
Out[78]: 8000

In [79]: np.in1d(out, p2).sum()
Out[79]: 2000
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily done using 1 call to [`random.randint()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint) to select a list and another call to [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) on the correct list. I'll assume list `frequent` contain 100 elements which are to be chose `80` percent times and `rare` contains `900` elements to be chose `20` percent times.

```
import random
a = random.randint(1,5)
if a == 1:
    # Case for rare numbers
    choice = random.choice(rare)
else:
    # case for frequent numbers
    choice = random.choice(frequent)
```