# a better way to do random sampling with a probability distribution?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I want to choose random items from an array but with certain probability distributions.
currently I do:
    `myarray =[5,5,5,95]`
which gets me a 75% chance of getting a 5 and 25% chance of getting a 95.

I have a lot more numbers though and it takes too much time to write out all those numbers, is there a faster/better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have an array with objects that contain any `value`, and a `weight` property that's a number.

```js
// data
const samples = [
  { value: 5, weight: 75 },
  { value: 95, weight: 25 }
];

// requested method
function randomSample (samples) {
  // [0..1) * sum of weight
  let sample =
    Math.random() *
    samples.reduce((sum, { weight }) => sum + weight, 0);

  // first sample n where sum of weight for [0..n] > sample
  const { value } = samples.find(
    ({ weight }) => (sample -= weight) < 0
  );

  return value;
}

// demo
const counts = { 5: 0, 95: 0 };

Array
  // take a million random samples
  .from({ length: 1000000 }, () => randomSample(samples))
  // count each sample
  .forEach(value => { counts[value]++; });

console.log(counts);
```

The data does not have to be in any particular order, nor do the weights need to add up to any particular sum.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function weightedChoice(array, weights) {
  let s = weights.reduce((a, e) => a + e);
  let r = Math.random() * s;
  return array.find((e, i) => (r -= weights[i]) < 0);
}

let randomArray =
    Array.apply(null, Array(32)).
    map(() => weightedChoice([5, 95], [75, 25]));
console.log(JSON.stringify(randomArray));
```

EDIT: Patrick was a bit faster than me, so I'll endorse his answer, and I'll just add that you don't absolutely need the sum to be 1, you can normalise the weight by finding out the sum by yourself.

EDIT EDIT: If you are really worried about performance in the case of needing many random values with the same weights, this would do better (by precalculating as much as possible):

```js
class WeightedSampler {
  constructor(elements, weights) {
    this.total = 0;
    this.elements = Array.from(elements);
    this.cweights = weights.map(weight => this.total += weight);
  }
  get() {
    let random = Math.random() * this.total;
    return this.elements.find((element, index) => random < this.cweights[index]);
  }
}

const sampler = new WeightedSampler(["M", "I", " "], [3, 9, 1]);
let randomArray = Array.apply(null, Array(32)).map(() => sampler.get());
console.log(randomArray.join(""));
```

Comment: This is good too. I suppose the advantage of this is that the weights don't have to sum to 1, the disadvantage being you have to include an extra loop to determine their sum before calculating the random choice.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: Haha, I was just writing that... :D

Comment: This algorithm is like the JS version of [this Python implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3679747/5743988).

Comment: By the way, for the logging, it would be easier to just do `Array(32).fill().map(...)`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: TIL of `fill`. Ill! :D

Comment: thanks all, these answers both work great!

Comment: Prompted by a recent upvote notification, I wanted to update the readability of my answer and decided that the disadvantage I mentioned before about the extra loop isn't really that big of a deal. Hope you don't mind that I borrowed a little from your answer.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts No worries. Prompted by your prompt, I added to my answer as well :D

Comment: Your update assumes that `elements` is immutable. I'd personally make a shallow copy of it before assigning it to `this.elements`, but otherwise I like the update. **edit** wish I could upvote again, but too stingy to make a bounty

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Done :)