# Python: Returning a set of examples randomly, classified correctly by a weight vector

Tags: python, python-2.7, random, classification

I'm trying to create a function that will take in a number of examples and some weights (a weight vector) and then return a single example (an x,y point) where y is classified as +1 or -1 based on the weight vector. In this case, "x" should be a dict (keys being a subset of the keys in weight), the values can be anything that has a nonzero "score" (given the weight vector).

I have some set-up that looks like this:

```
def getDataset(num_examples, weights):
    random.seed(50)
    def make_an_example():
         x = {}
         for i in range(weight):
         # update here?
         #After updating, I know you would set y = +1 or y = -1, "___" is what I'm not sure goes in:
         if ______: y = 1
         else: y = -1
         return (x,y)
    return [make_an_example() for _ in range(num_examples)]
```

I'm not totally sure what goes "in the middle" - I have tried messing with it but can't get something that works. Any suggestions would be very appreciated. Thank you!

example run/input call ("myfile.py" consists of the above code):

```
weights = {"hello":1, "world":1}
some_data = myfile.getDataset(3, weights)
```

The output would look something like this:

```
[({'world': 13}, 1), ({'hello': 339}, 1), ({'world': 44}, 1)]
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example input call to `getDataset`? (e.g. values for `num_examples` and `weights`), and possible example output? thanks

Comment: Updated with an input call and an example output!

Comment: Your example doesn't show how you want y to be determined. Can you describe it in simple language? Also, are you trying to use "weights" as a weighting vector for how commonly those appear in the output? If so, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679694/a-weighted-version-of-random-choice

Comment: Given an x (a dict whose keys are a subset of the keys of weights and values can be anything random with a nonzero score, given the weight vector), y should be +1 or -1 as classified by the weight vector. So y is determined by the weight vector. y = weights*x. Does that make sense?