# Randomly picking Items with Given Probabilities

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

Currently i'm working on a project where I need to code something in Python but stumbled upon some obstacles. I have an excel sheet with 692 items (stock keeping units) with their corresponding sales numbers. The items are in sequence from most sold till least sold. I calculated both the probability and cumulative probability for each item as can be seen in images 1 and 2 below:

[excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbZUp.png)

[excel sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJHtt.png)

Based on the cumulative probability and following formula: =INDEX(A$2:A$721;COUNTIF(H$2:H$721;"<="&RAND())+1)

randomly 20 items are selected from the 692 items to generate an order picking list, which can be seen in the following image:

[generated pick list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIcNl.png)

Basically i want to do the same in Python. Thus, select a number of items from a large list based on their probability.

I found the following code, but not sure how to use it:

```
    import random
def random_pick(some_list, probabilities):
    x = random.uniform(0, 1)
    cumulative_probability = 0.0
    for item, item_probability in zip(some_list, probabilities):
        cumulative_probability += item_probability
        if x < cumulative_probability: break
    return item
```

It would be great if someone could give me some directions in how to achieve this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/3679694/3001761

Comment: You can provide normal weights and cumulated weights via `random.choice` - no need to prog something yourself: [random.choices](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/random.html#random.choices)

Answer (score 2):

Use [random.choices](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/random.html#random.choices) and give it some probabilities:

```
from collections import Counter
from random import choices


data = [1,2,3,4]
prob = [1,1,8,1] # 3 about 8 times more likely to being choosen then 1,2 or 4

c = Counter(choices(data,prob,k=1000)) # generate 1000 and count

print(c)
```

Output:

```
Counter({3: 717, 1: 101, 2: 92, 4: 90})  # 3 being taken far more often - about 8:1:1:1 if
                                         # you close both eyes and squint really hard ;)
```