# How to select items from a list based on probability

Tags: python, python-3.x, probability

I have lists `a` and `b`

```
a = [0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]

b = [apple, gun, pizza, sword, pasta, chicken, elephant]
```

Now I want to create a new list c of 3 items

the 3 items are chosen form list b based on the probabilities in list a

the items should not repeat in list c

for example- output I am  looking for

```
c = [gun,sword,pizza]
```

or

```
c = [apple, pizza, pasta]
```

**note**
(sum of all values of list a is 1,number of items in list a and b is the same, actually i have a thousand items in both list a and b and i want to select hundred items from the list based on probability assigned to them,python3  )

Comment: If you're open to numpy then the answer is easy. Are you?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what this has to do with genetic algorithms or `fuzzywuzzy` so I'm removing those tags.

Comment: yes open to numpy

Comment: I'm not sure you need Numpy, just [`random.choices()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices).

Comment: Just realised the dupe I've suggested uses both python and numpy so it's covered

Comment: @Delgan the docs suggest that it uses replacement and there doesn't seem to be an argument to avoid it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679694/a-weighted-version-of-random-choice   this worked perfectly

Comment: @gokulgupta added a way to do it without numpy if you need

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `random.choices`:

```
>>> import random
>>> print(random.choices(
...     ['apple', 'gun', 'pizza', 'sword', 'pasta', 'chicken', 'elephant'], 
...     [0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
...     k=3
... ))
['gun', 'pasta', 'sword']
```

Edit: To avoid replacement, you can remove the selected item from the population:

```
def choices_no_replacement(population, weights, k=1):
    population = list(population)
    weigths = list(weights)    
    result = []
    for n in range(k):
        pos = random.choices(
            range(len(population)), 
            weights,
            k=1
        )[0]
        result.append(population[pos])
        del population[pos], weights[pos]
    return result
```

Testing:

```
>>> print(choices_no_replacement(
...     ['apple', 'gun', 'pizza', 'sword', 'pasta', 'chicken', 'elephant'],
...     [0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
...     k=3
... ))
['gun', 'pizza', 'sword']
```

Comment: The documentation suggests that this picks with replacement and I can't see a way to avoid that.

Comment: @roganjosh added a way to do it

Comment: I think it's just easier to use the numpy approach :) My "can't see a way to avoid that" was more in reference to `choices` not having an argument to prevent replacement. It seems some way behind the numpy method, but it's getting there :) Maybe Python 3.8 will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to define in advance how many items you want to pick (so, you don't do something like `k=3`) and you just have probabilities, you can do as below. Note that your probabilities do not need to add up to 1 as shown, they can be independent of each other. Admittedly, I am not addressing your issue of preventing possible repetitions:

```
a = [0.2, 0.3, 0.9, 0.1]
b = ['apple', 'gun', 'pizza', 'sword'] 

selected_items = [item for p,item in zip(a,b) if random.random()<p]
print(selected_items)
>>>['apple','pizza']
```