# How to assign probabilities based on certain condition?

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have run into a wall here. So i pull random sample of, lets say 10 elements, and i want to give them probabilities, based on some condition. Lets say that i have this random sample [1, 3, 5, 7, 13, 16, 6, 9, 22, 15] so i want to give each number  a probability based on the relative distance from int of 8. Further element is from 8, less the probability. In this case 7 and nine have same, biggest probabilities and 22 have the smallest?

I tried to find some numpy function, but with no success.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? (code speaking)

Comment: Try and look at the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679694/a-weighted-version-of-random-choice

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A weighted version of random.choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679694/a-weighted-version-of-random-choice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do two things. Create the probability, and select according to it. To create it

```
data = np.array([1, 3, 5, 7, 13, 16, 6, 9, 22, 15])
p = 1 / np.abs(data - 8)
```

(that's just and idea, you don't specify exactly how you want the probability to change with distance)

For the second part, `numpy.choice` function (*in recent* numpy versions) can accept the array `p` to select with that probability from `data`

Comment: Sum of probabilities goes way above 1. I'll just divide every element with sum of probabilitis, that will do the trick. Thanks for quick response!

Comment: @I.Rankovic: yes, just normalize by the sum