# How to produce a budget-constrained weighted random sample, where items have varying probabilities and weights?

Tags: python, numpy, random

Suppose I want to select two records from a set of three, where the probabilities of the three are 0.1, 0.5, and 0.4, respectively. Per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26196078/1840471), `numpy.random.choice` will work:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import random

df = pd.DataFrame({'prob': [0.1, 0.5, 0.4]})

random.seed(0)
random.choice(df.index, p=df.prob, size=2, replace=False)
# array([1, 2])
```

Now suppose each item also has a weight, and rather than selecting two items, I want to select a maximum weight. So if these items have weight of 4, 5, and 6, and I have a budget of 10, I could select {0, 1} or {0, 2}. The relative probabilities of each item being included would still be governed by the probabilities (though in practice I think an algorithm would return item 1 more often because its low weight can serve as a filler).

Is there a way to adapt `random.choice` for this, or another approach to yield this result?

Comment: Easiest way is to re-choice until you got a valid set. Does efficiency important?

Comment: The use case will be over a few hundred thousand records, so efficiency isn't critical but I'd like to minimize looping.

Comment: You can choose one item at a time and update the probabilities for each step.

Comment: BTW, why {3} is valid? There is a place to add item 1

Comment: You're right, updated. And yes I'll work on the one-item-at-a-time approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do, is using `np.random.choice` with the probabilities like you do but for the full size of you data. Then `reindex` the `df` with the new order you get from `np.random.choice`. Use [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) on the column weight and finally return only the index until it reaches the value you want.

```
def weighted_budgeted_random_sample_all(df, budget):
   random_index_order = np.random.choice( df.index, size = len(df), 
                                          p = df.prob, replace = False)
   s = df.reindex(random_index_order).weight.cumsum()
   return s[s <= budget].index.values
```

Now the problem with this method, is that with the `df` as in the question and a `budget` of 10, then some solutions are only the index 1 or 2 because if `random_index_order` is equal to `[2,1,0]` or `[1,2,0]` then the `cumsum` is higher than 10 at the second row.

See with a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), the use of `tuple` and `np.sort` are just to make the `Counter` work and easier to see the result:

```
from collections import Counter
print (Counter([ tuple(np.sort(weighted_budgeted_random_sample_all(df,10))) 
                 for i in range(1000)]))
# Counter({(0, 1): 167, (0, 2): 111, (1,): 390, (2,): 332})
```

as you can see, some draws were in the order with 2 and 3 as the first 2 values and the result is only 2 or 3 because the sum of their weights is 11.

But actually, if you try the same thing with a budget of 11, then you get the expected output:

```
print (Counter([ tuple(np.sort(weighted_budgeted_random_sample_all(df,11))) 
                 for i in range(1000)]))
# Counter({(0, 1): 169, (0, 2): 111, (1, 2): 720})
```

Here you find the three possibles set and the fact that the set `{1,2}` is obtained more often make sense.

I saw that you revised your question after a comment saying you *'ll work on the one-item-at-a-time approach*. I believe than doing this will have an effect on the overall probabilities but I don't know enough in probabilities to say why. If you really want, then I assume you can combine your approach and mine to gain some time:

```
def weighted_budgeted_random_sample_mixed(df, budget):
    ids = []
    total = 0
    dftemp = df.copy()
    while total < budget:
        remaining = budget - total
        dftemp = dftemp[dftemp.weight <= remaining]
        # Stop if there are no records with small enough weight.
        if dftemp.shape[0] == 0:
            break
        # New order
        new_index = np.random.choice( dftemp.index, size = len(dftemp), 
                                      p = (dftemp.prob/dftemp.prob.sum()), 
                                      replace = False)
        s = dftemp.reindex(new_index).weight.cumsum()
        #select only the necessary rows
        s = s[s <= remaining] 
        total += s.max() #last value in s which is less than remaining
        dftemp.drop(s.index, inplace=True)
        ids += s.index.tolist()
    return ids
```

Now for comparison with your method in terms of result:

```
#your approach
print (Counter([ tuple(np.sort(weighted_budgeted_random_sample(df,10))) 
                 for i in range(1000)]))
#Counter({(0, 1): 546, (0, 2): 454})

#mixed approach
print (Counter([ tuple(np.sort(weighted_budgeted_random_sample_mixed(df,10))) 
                 for i in range(1000)])
#Counter({(0, 1): 554, (0, 2): 446})
```

As you can see, the result are quite similar and the mixed approach should be faster on larger dataframe as it minimize looping in the `while`

Comment: Thank you this is great, and good to learn about `Counter`. I agree that the one-at-a-time approach affects probabilities, especially with few items (1 gets selected 55% of the time even though it has only a 10% probability). In practice I'll have hundreds of thousands of items to choose from, and hitting the target closely is more important, so this won't be such an issue.

Comment: @MaxGhenis glad it make it for you. thanks for confirming for the affects on probabilities, I'm learning about it these days for a new job I start soon :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-at-a-time approach:

1. Get the set of items with weight below the budget.
2. Select a random item from this set, according to each's probability.
3. Add this to a running list and remove it from the set of available items.
4. Repeat 1-3 until no remaining items can fill the gap between the accrued weight and the budget.

Here's a function to do it, which as expected only produces the sets {0, 1} and {0, 2} in the example:

```
def weighted_budgeted_random_sample(df, budget):
    """ Produce a weighted budgeted random sample.

    Args:
        df: DataFrame with columns for `prob` and `weight`.
        budget: Total weight budget.

    Returns:
        List of index values of df that constitute the sample.

    """
    ids = []
    total = 0
    while total < budget:
        remaining = budget - total
        df = df[df.weight <= remaining]
        # Stop if there are no records with small enough weight.
        if df.shape[0] == 0:
            break
        # Select one record.
        selection = random.choice(df.index, p=(df.prob / df.prob.sum()))
        total += df.loc[selection].weight
        df.drop(selection, inplace=True)
        ids.append(selection)
    return ids
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'weight': [4, 5, 6],
    'prob': [0.1, 0.5, 0.8]
})

weighted_budgeted_random_sample(df, 10)
# [2, 0]
```

This could probably be optimized by starting with `random.choice` for a number of items that wouldn't be constrained by the budget.