# How to manipulate random numbers in PHP?

Tags: php, random

I readed really a lot forums and problems here, but cant find the right solution.

So, most of you (I hope) know freebitco.in, you can win bitcoins every 1 hour. There is the following table. If you roll a number between 0-9885 you will get the following payout and etc.. But there is a very very little chance to roll number bigger than 9885. For example the change to get number bigger than **9885** is 5%, bigger than **9985** - 1%, bigger than **9993** - 0.001%, **10k** - impossible. So, how I can have a script like this?

[image]

Comment: You want to influence the `rand()` function running on someone else's server? There's no way for you to influence their server.

Comment: This is like trying to influence the lottery machine.

Comment: You are not understanding me. I want to create script like this.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to influence `rand()`, just get a random number and test its value against the ranges.

```
$val = mt_rand(0, 10000);
if ($val <= 9885) {
    $payout = 0.00000035;
} elseif ($val <= 9985) {
    $payout = 0.00000351;
} elseif ($val <= 9993) {
    $payout = 0.00003515;
} ...
```

Comment: What do you mean? You don't want equal probability for all numbers? The whole point of this is that the bigger payouts should be less frequent.

Comment: It should be `0-9885` 98.85% of the time, `9886-9985` should be 1%, `9986-9993` should be `0.08%`, etc.

Comment: If you want different percentages, you should use different number ranges. E.g. if you want the lowest payout to be 95%, it should be the range 0-9500.

Comment: Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679694/a-weighted-version-of-random-choice

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you would like to calculate the winner. However, you might just want to design an array, and use a random number and lookup in the array.

You might not want to have anymore probabilities, but if you like so, you can just add as an attribute in the array, then do any math you wish in the `if` statement or `else`.

```
$lookup = array(
    "0" => array(
        "luck" => 9885,
        "payout" => 0.00000035,
        "probability" => 0.5,
    ),
    "1" => array(
        "luck" => 9886,
        "payout" => 0.00000351,
        "probability" => 0.3,
    ),
    "2" => array(
        "luck" => 9993,
        "payout" => 0.00003515,
        "probability" => 0.1,
    ),
    "3" => array(
        "luck" => 9997,
        "payout" => 0.00035149,
        "probability" => 0.09,
    ),
    "4" => array(
        "luck" => 9999,
        "payout" => 0.00351494,
        "probability" => 0.009,
    ),
    "5" => array(
        "luck" => 9999,
        "payout" => 0.03514939,
        "probability" => 0.001,
    ),
);

BitocoinPayout(mt_rand(0, 10000), $lookup);

function BitocoinPayout($luck_number, $lookup)
{

    foreach ($lookup as $value) {
        if ((int) $luck_number < (int) $value["luck"]) {
            // or do other math
            echo "YAAAY! You just won Stephanie Kostova's jackpot of " . $value["payout"] . " Bitcoin! ";
            break;
        } else {
            continue;
            // or do other math
        }
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
YAAAY! You just won Stephanie Kostova's jackpot of 3.5E-7 Bitcoin!
```

Comment: You're not using the `probability` columns for anything.