# Could a function call itself with different parameters inside its definition?

Tags: python, function, call

this function has 3 modes, i.e. 'hh' 'ih' and 'ho'.

```py
    def mutate_add_connection(self, mode = 'hh'):
        if mode == 'hh':    # hidden --> hidden
            node_a = random.choice(self.hidden_nodes_dict.values())
            node_b = random.choice(self.hidden_nodes_dict.values())
            self.connect_node_pair(node_a,node_b, 'sort')
        elif mode == 'ih':  # input --> hidden
            node_a = random.choice(self.input_nodes_dict.values())
            node_b = random.choice(self.hidden_nodes_dict.values())
            node_b.set_links((node_a,random.choice([-1, 1])))
        elif mode == 'ho':  # hidden --> output
            node_b.set_links((node_a,random.choice([-1, 1])))
            node_a = random.choice(self.hidden_nodes_dict.values())
            node_b = random.choice(self.output_nodes_dict.values())
```

In practice of adding-connection mutate, I need to use these 3 modes with a probability. Let't say 33.33% for each mode.

So I am planning to add a mode 'auto' in this function. In order to call the 3 mode above "randomly".

```py
    def mutate_add_connection(self, mode = 'hh'):
        if mode == 'auto':
            chosen_mode = random.choice(['hh','ih','ho'])
            self.mutate_add_connection(mode=chosen_mode)
        # the code above .......
```

But I am not sure if it is a good idea. Could you suggest a better way to achieve my propose? Thanks~

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While there are often good uses for recursive functions, it's not really needed here. Just reassign the `mode` argument.

```
    def mutate_add_connection(self, mode = 'hh'):
        if mode == 'auto':
            mode = random.choice(['hh','ih','ho'])
        # the code above .......
```

Comment: great, thank you for such a clean code. But what if the probabilities to choose them are different?( Let's say, 10.5%, 50.5% and 39%)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679694/a-weighted-version-of-random-choice

Comment: How you choose the auto mode is independent of how you execute the rest of the code using it.