# How to get uniform distribution by weighted probability in python in a dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, probability, uniform-distribution

I have already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679694/a-weighted-version-of-random-choice) and I know `numpy.random.choice`, but my question is slightly different.

Given that, I have a dataset as below:

```
dict ={"Number of polyps":[10,8,3,1,2,6,13],
        "Right ":[3,2,3,1,0,3,3],
        "Left":[2,2,4,15,6,7,1] }

dt = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

so, it is:

```
Number of polyps  Right   Left
            10       3     2
             8       2     2
             3       3     4
             1       1    15
             2       0     6
             6       3     7
            13       3     1
```

I need to refill the `Right` and `Left` column by below requirement

1. Sum of `Right` and `Left` is equal to `Number of polyps`
2. The values of `Right` and `Left` comes from weighted probability of **their current** value

For example, for a given row as below:

```
Number of polyps  Right   Left
            10       3     2
```

so, for this row it could be as below. Here `0.6= 3/(3+2)` and `0.4= 2/(3+2)`:

```
nr = np.random.choice(["Right","Left"],size=10, replace=True,p=[0.6,0.4])
rightCount = list.count('Right')
leftCount = list.count('Left')
print(rightCount)
print(leftCount)
```

After updating this row will be:

```
Number of polyps  Right   Left
            10       3     7
```

***The problem is, I must do it for all the rows in dataset, but I am not sure how to do it!***

Comment: If it works for one row, putting it in a for loop will make it work for all rows ... ?

Answer (score 5):

You're essentially drawing from the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).  It is implemented in NumPy as [`numpy.random.binomial`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.binomial.html):

```
>>> dt["Right"] = np.random.binomial(dt["Number of polyps"], dt["Right"]/(dt["Right"]+dt["Left"]))
>>> dt["Left"] = dt["Number of polyps"] - dt["Right"]
```

Here, for each row we perform `dt["Number of polyps"]` binary-choice trials, with each trial selecting `Right` with probability `dt["Right"]/(dt["Right"]+dt["Left"])` and `Left` otherwise.

Comment: But `Binomial distribution` is slightly different from `Uniform`? Right? @NPE

Comment: @Jeff: There's nothing uniform about your distribution.  (Uniform distribution is continuous, whereas your case is discrete.)