# Generating a random list from a tuple but being able to select percentage of each item

Tags: python, random

I want to generate a list of say length 10000 from two items ('yes','no'). And the code I haev does that. The problem is, it generates ~50% yes and 50% no. How can I modify this code so that I can set the percentage of time it selects yes. Suppose i want yes like 36.7% of the time. And then it should select the remaining 'no' the remaining 63.3% time.
Code is below:

```py
import random

category = ('yes','no')
length_of_field = 10000
print(length_of_field)
print(type(category))
category_attribute = [random.choice(category) for _ in range(length_of_field)]
print('\ncategory:')
print(len(category_attribute))
print(type(category_attribute))

from collections import Counter
a= Counter(category_attribute).keys()
b= Counter(category_attribute).values()
print(a,b)
```

Comment: So is this absolution percentage? Meaning is I say 30% `No` in a list of 100 elements then exactly 30 of them must be `No` and 70 must be `Yes`?

Comment: [A weighted version of random.choice](//stackoverflow.com/q/3679694)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp  it is built into random.choice: https://docs.python.org/dev/library/random.html#random.choices

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A weighted version of random.choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679694/a-weighted-version-of-random-choice)

Comment: @PatrickArtner the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39976962/669576) in the link addresses that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import numpy as np 
alist = np.random.choice(["No","Yes"], 1000, p=[0.633, 0.367])
```

built-in

```
import random 
alist = random.choices(["no", "yes"], weights=[0.633, 0.367], k=1000)
```

or

```
def generate_some_dist(p, n):
    '''
    p: 0~1, proba to generate yes
    n: size
    '''
    a = []
    for i in range(n):
        if random.random() <= p:
            a.append("yes")
        else:
            a.append("no")
    return a

a = generate_some_dist(.367, 10000)
```

or

```
p = 0.367
n = 1000
a = ["yes" if random.random() <= p else "No" for _ in range(n) ]
```

Comment: Please use the built-in version before using a third party library....

Comment: https://docs.python.org/dev/library/random.html#random.choices can do it without numpy