# I want to make random choice but with weights for its values

Tags: python, random

I'm making an RPG loot generator, and I'm trying to make a random choice with weights for each rarity of items. How do I do that?

```
Item_rarity = ["Common", "Uncommon", "Superior", "Rare", "Legendary"]
Rarity_choice = random.choice(Item_rarity)
```

I expect that Common = 50%; Uncommon = 30%; Superior = 14%; Rare = 5%; Legendary = 1%.
How do I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58346227/generating-a-random-list-from-a-tuple-but-being-able-to-select-percentage-of-eac/58346306#58346306

Comment: Another duplicate (more suitable IMO): [A weighted version of random.choice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3679694/4518341)

Answer (score 5):

Use [random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices):

> random.choices(population, weights=None, *, cum_weights=None, k=1)
>
> Return a k sized list of elements chosen from the population with
>   replacement.
>
> If a weights sequence is specified, selections are made according to the relative weights.

```
import random

item_rarity = ["Common", "Uncommon", "Superior", "Rare", "Legendary"]
weights = [50, 30, 14, 5, 1]

print(random.choices(item_rarity, weights)[0])
# 'Common'
```

Note that it returns a list, even if you just want one item, hence the `[0]` to get the one item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient, but general purpose.

Here we get a list from a dict of {'thing':how_many_times}:

```py
import random

def listProb(adcit):
    res=[]
    for k,v in adcit.items():
        for occur in range(v):
            res.append(k)
    return res

Item_rarity = listProb({'common':50, 'uncommon':30,})
print(Item_rarity)

Rarity_choice = random.choice(Item_rarity)
print(Rarity_choice)
```

and get something like

```
['common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'common', 'uncommon', 'uncommon', 'uncommon', 'uncommon', 'uncommon', 'uncommon', 'uncommon', 'uncommon', 'uncommon', 'uncommon', 'uncommon', 'uncommon', 'uncommon', 'uncommon', 'uncommon', 'uncommon', 'uncommon', 'uncommon', 'uncommon', 'uncommon', 'uncommon', 'uncommon', 'uncommon', 'uncommon', 'uncommon', 'uncommon', 'uncommon', 'uncommon', 'uncommon', 'uncommon']
uncommon
```