# Generate column in pandas dataframe with specific frequency from a list

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a dataframe with 4 columns 'date', 'age', 'conversion', 'marital_status'. Where marital status is one of 4 choices (married, divorced, single, unknown). 
I am able to create the dataframe using the following code. However, I am not sure how to specify the frequency. I want married to be 50%, divorced 30%, single 15% and rest unknown. How do I do this.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

random.seed(30)
np.random.seed(30)

start_date,end_date = '1/1/2015','12/31/2019'
date_rng = pd.date_range(start= start_date, end=end_date, freq='D')
length_of_field = date_rng.shape[0]
df = pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=['date'])
df['age'] = np.random.randint(18,100,size=(len(date_rng)))
df['conversion'] = np.random.randint(0,2,size=(len(date_rng)))
marital_status = ('divorced','married','single','unknown')
group_1 = [random.choice(marital_status) for _ in range(length_of_field)]
df['marital_status'] = group_1
print('\ndf:')
print(df)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679694/a-weighted-version-of-random-choice?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.random.choice`. `p` parameter specifies the probability of each class.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.choice(marital_status, len(length_of_field), p = [0.3, 0.5, 0.15, 0.5])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
np.random.choice(['divorced','maried','single','unknown'], size = len(date_rng), p = [0.5, 0.3,0.15,0.05])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random.choices` (inspired by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679694/a-weighted-version-of-random-choice)):

```
marital_status = random.choices(
    population=['divorced','married','single','unknown'],
    weights=[0.3, 0.5, 0.15, 0.05],
    k=df.shape[0]
)
df['marital_status'] = marital_status
```