# Generate random probability with non-uniform distribution in Numpy automatically

Tags: python, numpy

In `Numpy` we can use `np.random.choice(N, data.shape[0], p=[0.6, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.05])` to randomly generate random samples. When the number of N is small, I can fill `p` manually. However, how to generate `p` automatically with that non-uniform distribution, e.g., the probability decreases from left to right or vice versa, when N is big, e.g., N=50 or N=100?

As far as I know, the following method can generate `p` automatically, however it seems that the result is still a uniform distribution.

```
values = [np.random.rand() for _ in range(N)]
p = [v/sum(values) for v in values]
```

How to obtain this kind of `p=[0.6, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.05]` automatically?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679694/a-weighted-version-of-random-choice

Comment: @Compsciismathbase2 The answers do not explain how the probability distribution is or the answers only explain when the pre-defined probability is given. I think generating exponential/geometric distribution before the ```p``` can be used.