# How do I assign weight to my lists using python's random.choice?

Tags: python

I'm very new to Python and will probably get down voted for such a simple question but I can't seem to find the answer on my own. I'm trying to use random.choice to choose a random result from a random list. I understand how to add weight to each item in a list but that's not what I'm trying to do. I want to add weight to each list so that results appear from certain lists more often than others. My function is below. My apologies in advance for any formatting issues!

```py
import random


def roll_item():
    common = ["C1", "C2", "C3"]
    uncommon = ["U1", "U2", "U3"]
    rare = ["R1", "R2"]

    x = ([common], [uncommon], [rare])
    y = random.choice(x)
    for items in y:
        print(random.choice(items))


roll_item()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A weighted version of random.choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679694/a-weighted-version-of-random-choice)

Comment: Is `random.choices` what you're looking for?  You could do: `y = random.choices([common,uncommon,rare],[10,5,3])`, then `y` would be chosen as the list with ratio `10:5:3`

Comment: That is exactly what I needed! Thanks so much. I read the linked question earlier, when I was trying to figure this out my own, but it wasn't clicking with me.