# Python: unique weighted random values

Tags: python-3.x

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679694/a-weighted-version-of-random-choice) thread I found out that I can use an approach with the `random.choices` for my needs:

```
class Weights:
    ITEM = {
        'a': 0.5,
        'b': 0.4,
        'c': 0.3,
        'd': 0.2,
        'e': 0.1
    }

import random
slot_1 = random.choices(population=list(Weights.ITEM.keys()), weights=list(Weights.ITEM.values()), k=1)[0]
slot_2 = ...?
slot_3 = ...?
```

Is it possible for me to get an array with the `k=3` that will have "unique" results (probably `[a,b,c]`) or somehow to exclude any previously selected value from the next call (with `k=1`)?
For example lets say `slot_1` got `"b"` and `slot_2` will get a random from the list of everything else without the `"b"` value.
This step can be sensitive to the performance and I think that creating new arrays each time is not a good idea.
Maybe there is something except `random.choices` that can be applied in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take all the samples all at once using numpy's random.choice  with the `replace = False` option (assuming the weights are just renormalized between steps,) and store them using multiple assignment, to get it into one line of code.

```
import numpy as np

slot_1, slot_2, slot_3 = np.random.choice(list(Weights.ITEM.keys()), size = 3, replace=False, p=list(Weights.ITEM.values()))
```

More generally, you could have a function that generated arbitrary length subsamples (k is length, n is number of samples):

```
def a(n,k,values,weights):
    a = np.split(np.random.choice(values, size = n*k,replace=False, p=weights), n)
    return [list(sublist) for sublist in a]

>>> a(3,5, range(100), [.01]*100)
[[39, 34, 27, 91, 88], [19, 98, 62, 55, 38], [37, 22, 54, 11, 84]]
```

Comment: Is it correct that `random.choices` accepts any weighted values when `np.random.choice` takes only an array with `sum == 1` ?

Comment: This appears to be the case, yes.

```>>> a(3,5, range(100), [1]*100)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#30>", line 1, in <module>
    a(3,5, range(100), [1]*100)
  File "<pyshell#28>", line 2, in a
    a = np.split(np.random.choice(values, size = n*k,replace=False, p=weights), n)
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 926, in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.choice
ValueError: probabilities do not sum to 1```

It's correctable by using:
```map(lambda x: x/sum(myweights), myweights)```

Comment: You might want to throw that through a ```list``` since it returns a generator though.