# how to select random number in different proportion in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list `['a','b','c','d']` and I want to randomly select

`'a' = 75 %`

`'b' = 15 %`

`'c' =  5 %`

`'d' =  5 %`

Times how do I achieve this in python

thanks in advance.

Comment: All your choices are 'a'

Comment: Anyway, there is an (off-site) answer at https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-get-a-weighted-random-choice-in-python . I guess there is probably also a duplicate on SO but I haven't looked hard for it.

Comment: its simple simply use the `randint()` function in your script for random percentage values

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679694/a-weighted-version-of-random-choice

Comment: Yes okay, looks like `random.choices` supports `weights` - so just use that with `k=1` and then it's not dependent on numpy (`random.choice` doesn't support a weights parameter)

Comment: So anyway... `random.choices("abcd", weights=[75,15,5,5], k=1)[0]`. But given the dup, I'm not going to post it as an answer.

Comment: @alani thank you alani :)