# Generate list of numbers from a list with probability weights

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, probability

How would one go about generating a list of random numbers from a list of 35 numbers with given probabilities:

Probability of number in range (1,5) - *p1* = 0.5

Probability of number in range (6,15) - *p2* = 0.25

Probability of number in range (16,35) - *p3* = 0.25

I tried using `numpy.random.choice()` but I have no idea how to jam in possible ***lists*** of numbers.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
You seem to be asking for a personal tutorial; this is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I assume you meant generate a random number from a list with weights, otherwise please elaborate on what you mean. Thank you.

Comment: @Ehsan No, I meant generate a list of numbers with those weights. Basically generating a discrete source with an alphabet of 35 symbols whose values should be in one of the ranges I mentioned in my question.

Comment: @ZlatanRadovanovic what is the size of your list you want to generate? is it with or without replacement? You can set them all in arguments of `np.random.choice` in my answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A weighted version of random.choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679694/a-weighted-version-of-random-choice)

Comment: @Ehsan I overlooked the size argument in the function, all good now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select uniformly from each group:

```
p=np.array([0.5/5]*5+[0.25/30]*30)
np.random.choice(np.arange(1,36),p=p/p.sum())
```

**UPDATE**:

and if you would like to select a list of random numbers (you can also set with or without replacement flag):

```
np.random.choice(np.arange(1,36), size=N, replace=True, p=p/p.sum())
```

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this by selecting the appropriate range with the specified probabilities, then use the chosen range as an argument to `random.choice`:

```
range_set = [range(1,6), range(6, 16), range(16, 36)]
random.choice(*random.choices(range_set, [0.5, 0.25, 0.25]))
```

This assumes that you want a uniform choice within a given range.