# How to randomly or by giving probabilities choose between options in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, probability

For example

```py
a = "a"
b = "b"
c = "c"
d = "d"
```

taking these variables and choosing a random one

```py
a = "a"
b = "b"
```

taking these variables, at a 75% chance choosing a and at a 25% chance choosing b

Comment: Possibly you're looking for something like https://stackoverflow.com/q/3679694/3001761, but it's not clear to me.

Answer (score -1):

You can add weights to `random.choices` This is how I did it:

```py
import random

lst= ["a", "b"]
print(random.choices(lst, weights=(0.75, 0.25), k=1))
```

k = 1 represents the amount of values to choose from the list, which, in our case, is only 1.

Comment: **the weights MUST add up to 1**, `random.choices([1, 2, 3], weights=[100, 100, 100])` does not throw any error.

Comment: I've learned probability this way. If you've learned it a different way, then feel free to use your way.

Comment: The point is more that you seem to be making claims about the API that aren't true. [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) **does not** require floats that add to 1, because it will normalise them to that internally anyway.

Comment: If it makes you happy, then fine, I'll change it

Comment: That's not a particularly constructive attitude. It's not about anyone's happiness; we're building a collection of high-quality technical information, it needs to be *correct*. This is also reflected in the edits that have repeatedly been applied to your posts to remove *"Hope this helps!"*, please do learn from those.

Comment: Apologies. I was simply **trying** to be nice