# How to randomly choose a tuple from a list of tuples

Tags: python, random, tuples

I need to randomly choose a tuple from a list of tuples given probabilities to be chosen for each tuple.

I'm trying the following code:

```
from numpy.random import choice
v = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
pr = [0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4]
print(choice(v, p=pr))
```

However, I get this message: ValueError: a must be 1-dimensional

How can fix that issue?

Comment: Why are you using numpy? Use the `random` module. Numpy is for working with numpy arrays

Comment: See the answers (and the comments) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679694/a-weighted-version-of-random-choice.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the same with the random module and the "weights" parameter:

```
import random
v = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
pr = [0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4]
print(*random.choices(v, weights=pr))
```

If you still need a numpy array, you can create it after getting the random tuple:

```
import random
import numpy as np

v = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
pr = [0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4]
rand_pr = np.array(*random.choices(v, weights=pr))
print(rand_pr)
```

Comment: Thanks for giving another insight, please use `print(*random....)` for output to be proper item (1-d)

Answer (score 0):

Convert items of v from tuple to str which is one-d object

```
from numpy.random import choice

v = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
pr = [0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4]
print(choice(list(map(str, v)), p = pr))
```

---

**Method-2**

```
from numpy.random import choice

ind = list(range(4))
v = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
pr = [0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4]
print(v[choice(ind, p = pr)])
```

Answer (score 0):

your v has to be 1-D array-like or int
as a workaround you can make a list of indexes of your v list, randomly chose an index and print v[index]

```
from numpy.random import choice
v = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
a = [0,1,2,3]
pr = [0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4]
print(v[(choice(a, p=pr))])
```

or for more universal usage:

```
from numpy.random import choice
v = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
a = []
for i in range (0,len(v)):
    a.append(i)
pr = [0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4]
print(v[(choice(a, p=pr))])
```