# How can I left join between two df by multiple conditions and dynamic probabilities?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I left join between two df by multiple conditions and dynamic probabilities?

DF A:
[image]

DF B:
[image]

I would like to left join 3 times between tables A and B and the conditions should be dynamic.
It's a bit complex so I'll try to explain with an example:

In table A -
Column A should contain one number from table B by this logic-
All the numbers in table B that are equal/less than the amount we have in the amount column in table A.
So for instance: 120 (table A) should get one of the following in table B - 120,110,100,90,80.
The number should be selected by probabilities - I want to be able to define probabilities for those numbers (for example, 120 - 20%, 110 - 5%, 100 - 50%, 90 - 10%, 80 - 15%).

Column B should contain one number from table B by this logic-
All the numbers in table B that are greater and not equal to 999 to the amount we have in the amount column in table A.
So for instance: 120 (table A) should get one of the following in table B - 130,140,150,160,170.
The number should be selected by probabilities - I want to be able to define probabilities for those numbers (for example, 130 - 20%, 140 - 5%, 150 - 50%, 160 - 10%, 170 - 15%).

Column C in table A should always get 999.

Hopefully I managed to explain myself.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't comprehend your logic and am not sure you are defining a merge/join as in your logic B gets from B sometimes.  Possibly you are talking about this... https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html

Comment: So, just to make sure; when you chose the number in table B, the given probabilities is the probability that you chose a given number, right? What should be in which column (Column A, B?)

Comment: Correct @CutePoison

Comment: Should that number be in the entire A or B column or just one of them? I.e do you pick an element, based on the probability, place it in Row 1 (col A) and then pick another one (based on the other logic) and place that in Row 1( col B), then you move on to Row 2 and do the same?

Comment: The number in column A should be different from the number in column B - based on the logic I've described.

Comment: Yes, but is it run one time? Do you pick a number, fill up *entire* column A (all rows with that one number, e.g 120) and then *entire* column B (based on the logic), or do you pick a number for each row?

Comment: Pick a number for each row

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234362/discussion-between-abc-and-cutepoison).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to understand exactly what you wan't, but I'll provide some tips:

Way to select based on the distribution (probability):

1. Create an array with the given cumulated-probability intervals e.g
   `prob_in = [0,0.2,0.25,0.75,0.85,1]` #20%+5%+50%+10%+15%
   and an array with your numbers corresponding to the probabilities
   `num_pick = [120,110, 100, 90, 80]`
2. Draw a number from the uniform-distribution [0,1], called `u` (say you get `u=0.35`).
3. Check in which interval `u` is, i.e in the third interval [0.25,0.75] thus you pick the third element in `num_pick` (which is 100)
4. Do what you want with that number
   This might be much to do, luckily you can use the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679694/a-weighted-version-of-random-choice) SO question

```py
from numpy.random import choice
draw = choice(list_of_candidates, number_of_items_to_pick,
              p=probability_distribution)
```

remember to decide if `replace=False/True` should be used i.e can the same item be chosen multiple times?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the issue is that the 2nd array you mentioned (num_pick) should be dynamic. For 120 the array should be as you said num_pick = [120,110, 100, 90, 80]. But for 140 for example the array should be [140,130,120,110,100]

Comment: This was an answer for Logic A (how to pick a number) - does the probabilities for picking the number (logic A) change aswell?