# How to generate random numbers according to a custom probability density function (Python)?

Tags: python, random, scipy, probability-density, probability-distribution

I have a list containing random variables X and the fractions they occur; so if I plot these I get a probability density function. I am wondering how I can then use this probability density function to generate some random numbers?

I've used scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline to obtain a Python function for this data. How do I use this function to generate random numbers?

Comment: What is your definition of *`random number`*?

Comment: I'd guess your spline interpolation expects an input from 0-1, you can easily generate that with `random.random()` or various other methods (e.g. from `numpy` if you need an array of random values). I feel like you've done the hard part already....

Comment: if you repeate the same value on list - ie `[a, b, b, b]` - then it has bigger probability when you get random item from list - `random( [a, b, b, b] )` - `a` has probabilty `0.25`, `b` has `0.75` - so if you could convert `fractions` to integer values then you could use them to repeate variables in list. Probably some function in `numpy` may do the same.

Comment: What I mean to do is for example, numpy.random.normal generates numbers according to a Gaussian distribution, how do I generate the same thing but using my own distribution? @PM77-1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A weighted version of random.choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679694/a-weighted-version-of-random-choice)

Comment: Do you have a list of numbers as well as their weights?  If so, consider `random.choices` (using base Python's `random` module).

Comment: random.choices may work. If I do `x=np.linspace(0,50,a)` then `random.choices(x, b, my_function(x))` where a and b are some integers. So to emulate the behavior of a probability density function in math, I would just have to set a to be very large compared to b? @PeterO.

Answer (score 2):

To rephrase your question, you have come up with a pdf ("a list containing random variables X and the fractions they occur") and want to know how you can draw random samples from a distribution that has this pdf. There are 2 ways (i know of) to do this depending on how formal you want to be.

**TLDR: For simple cases use the NumPy implementation as it's clean, simple and fast. If you want a more formal version because you're using a larger statistical framework then maybe the SciPy version fits better.**

**SciPy**

If you want it to fit into the SciPy distribution framework then you can use the `rv_discrete` class and extend it. In your case this would look like:

```
from scipy.stats import rv_discrete

# these are your variables X
vals = [1, 2, 3]
# these are the fractions they occur
probs = [0.2, 0.5, 0.3]

# define discrete distribution
distrib = rv_discrete(values=(range(len(vals)), probs)) 

# sample 10 values from this distribution
distrib.rvs(size=10)
array([1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1])

# distrib outputs indices in vals, not actual vals
[vals[x] for x in distrib.rvs(size=10)]
[3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

And a quick speed test for good measure:

```
%timeit [vals[x] for x in distrib.rvs(size=10000)]
2.34 ms ± 195 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**NumPy**

As mentioned in the comments you can just use NumPy directly using the `np.random.choice` function.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.choice(vals, size=10, p=probs)
array([2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2])
```

Although it's not part of the SciPy distribution framework, it is simple and clean and as the below shows faster:

```
%timeit np.random.choice(vals, size=10000, p=probs)
639 µs ± 204 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Part of the speed improvement of NumPy over SciPy is due to the difference in how they generate the pseudo-random numbers that underlie the sampling process. NumPy has upgraded their default PRNG process to the [PCG family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permuted_congruential_generator) of random number generators whereas SciPy are still using [Mersenne-Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister). They announced this [here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.17.0-notes.html) and if you are curious about how it works I've written a simple explainer [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/where-does-python-get-its-random-numbers-from-81dece23b712). There's also *a lot* more detail [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/16313) between the experts.

We can see the impact of this speed improvement by passing the NumPy PRNG to SciPy:

```
# default SciPy
distrib = rv_discrete(values=(range(len(vals)), probs))
%timeit [vals[x] for x in distrib.rvs(size=1000000)]
358 ms ± 204 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# SciPy but we pass NumPy's new PCG PRNG
np_seed = np.random.default_rng(123)
distrib = rv_discrete(values=(range(len(vals)), probs), seed=np_seed)
%timeit [vals[x] for x in distrib.rvs(size=1000000)]
221 ms ± 15.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So using NumPy's PRNG is about `1.5x` faster.