# Python Choice, get / return selected Wieght value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use .Choices to select a value randomly whith weight value.

Is it possible to store the used weight value to a variable?

```
var = random.choices(population=A, B, C, weights=[20, 20, 60])
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to determine which weight was chosen?

Comment: Check out this answer [relevant to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39976962/4053024)

Answer (score 1):

Just store it before you give it to the function. You must also change the way you assign the population. Your Code sould look more like this:

```
my_weights = [20, 20, 60]
my_population = ["A", "B", "C"]
var = random.choices(population = my_population, weights = my_weights)
```

Like this the code should ork an you could access the weights and population afterwards in `my_weights` and `my_population`.

If you want to access the chosen weight, you can do it like this:

```
chosen_weight = [weight for i, weight in enumerate(my_weights) if my_population[i] in var]
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a way to attach the weight to your choice. For that, a `dataclass` would work well.

```
from random import choices
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Choice:
    value: int
    weight: int

a = Choice(value=3, weight=20)
b = Choice(value=4, weight=20)
c = Choice(value=5, weight=60)

all_choices = choices(population=(a, b, c), weights=[a.weight, b.weight, c.weight])
first_choice = all_choices[0]
print(first_choice.value, first_choice.weight)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can store it before using and then just pass the variable to the weights argument

```
myweights = [20, 20, 60]
var = random.choices(population=[A, B, C], weights=myweights)
```

However `random.choices()` only returns a list of elements chosen from the population, so you can't get the weights after.

Comment: Thanks, but this its not what i need.
I would like to use futher the weight selected / used by the .choices function.

Comment: @Romeh You can, just use **myweights** every time you need to. You can also change them dynamically this way.