# Generate random samples with specified properties from a population in Python

Tags: python, random, sample

Suppose I have a population divided by nationality according to the following proportions (%):

```
percentages = {'Germany': 0.4, 'France': 0.25, 'Greece': 0.15, 'Poland': 0.1, 'Norway': 0.05, 'Others': 0.05}
```

Now I need to generate samples from this population. Is there a way in Python to generate a sample of size `n` from the population?

For example, if `n = 50`, I would expect to have something like:

```
sample = {'Germany': 22, 'France': 10, 'Greece': 8, 'Poland': 6, 'Norway': 3, 'Others': 1}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A weighted version of random.choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679694/a-weighted-version-of-random-choice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a built in method in random

```
import random
random.choices(
     population=list(percentages.keys()), 
     weights=list(percentages.values()),
     k=50
)
```

So then you can do:

```
import random
percentages = {'Germany': 0.4, 'France': 0.25, 'Greece': 0.15, 'Poland': 0.1, 'Norway': 0.05, 'Others': 0.05}

r = random.choices(
     population=list(percentages.keys()),
     weights=list(percentages.values()),
     k=50
)

sample = {key: 0 for key in percentages}
for key in r:
    sample[key] += 1

print(sample)
```

Might not be the most efficiënt method, but it works.

Comment: could use `collections.Counter` instead of the loop. Nice answer +1