# Generating a 1D random walk with random module

Tags: python, random, module, random-walk

I was trying to generate a random walk in 1D just with the `random` module. If a position at a certain moment is `x`, then the next position can be `x+1` or `x-1` with equal probability. I need to find the final position after 100 moves (`start=0`).

I have developed the following code, but I am not sure how I should should define the equal probability among the choices.

```
import random
def randomwalk1D(n):
    x = 0
    start = x
    xposition = [start]
    probabilities = [0.5, 0.5]
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        step = random.choice(probabilities)
        if step > probabilities[0]:
            x += 1
        elif step < probabilities[1]:
            x -= 1
        xposition.append(start)
    return xposition
```

The function return just zeroes as result (putting `n = 100`). I only want to only use the `random` module. Could someone advise on what to do from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1. You need to pass the choices of `-1` and `1` to `random.choice()`, not the weights of those choices. You can also get rid of the direct comparisons with the elements from `probabilities` and the sampled step. If you want weighted sampling, [use `numpy.random.choice`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3679694/17769815).
2. You're adding `start` to the `xpositions` list repeatedly, even though you never update it. To resolve, append `x` instead, which represents the actual current position.

Here is a code snippet that resolves both issues.

```py
import random
def randomwalk1D(n):
    x = 0
    start = x
    xposition = [start]
    probabilities = [-1, 1]
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        x += random.choice(probabilities)
        xposition.append(x)
    return xposition

print(randomwalk1D(100))
```

Answer (score 2):

There's some good answers already posted, so I'll add that there's some optimizations that could be made:

```
import random
def randomwalk1D(n):
    x = 0
    xposition = [x]
    for _ in range(n):
        step = random.randint(0,1)
        if step:
            x += 1
        else:
            x -= 1
        xposition.append(x)
    return xposition
```

This removes `start`, as we can simply define `x = 0` and since you want your list to start with this value, instantiate the list with `[x]` included.

```
    x = 0
    xposition = [x]
```

Instead of `for i in range(1, n + 1):`, we're using `for _ in range(n)`.  This cycles the same amount of times, but starting at the default of 0 instead.   Because there's no use of the variable `i`, we're using `_` which is a standard to indicate that the value doesn't matter, we only want to cycle a certain number of times.

```
    for _ in range(n):
```

Instead of a list of numbers and `random.randchoice`, we're using `random.randint(0,1)`.  This range is inclusive, so it will return 0, or 1.

```
step = random.randint(0,1)
```

Then, because `1` is "truthy", we can simply test `if step:` to test if 1, and then use `else:` otherwise.

```
        if step:
            x += 1
        else:
            x -= 1
```

```
>>> randomwalk1D(10) 
[0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4]
```

Edit:

If weighted numbers are needed, the following modification could be made to the code:

```
        choices = (0,1)
        weights = (10,1)
        step = random.choices(choices, weights=weights).pop()
```

`step` will be defined as either 0 or 1, with 0 being 10 times more likely than 1.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two separate problems in your code, that are leading to the results you are seeing:

- The result of your `random.choice(probabilities)` expression is always a value of 0.5. With that, both of the following if statements can never be triggered, and `x` always remains the same value.
- When you append the steps with `xposition.append` you are appending the start value, which also remains the same over iterations of the for loop, so only 0 will ever be appended.

Additionally, there might be some confusion about what random.choice actually does.
It takes a iterable, and uniformly chooses one of it's items to output.  Since you have given it `[0.5, 0.5]` that means, you can only ever get 0.5 as an output.   Perhaps you could just generate a uniformly random number, using `random.uniform(0, 1)` as `step`. That way you can just decide the direction to walk in based on `step >= 0.5` or `step < 0.5`.