# Is it possible to customize the random function to avoid too much repetition of words?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, random

Theoretically, when randomization is used, the same word may be printed several consecutive times, or it may be printed repeatedly (for example, 3 times out of 5 attempts the same word may be printed). I know, this is correct, this is right and normal.

I would like to set the same value of a variable to be printed again only after four times, therefore on the fifth attempt. I simply want to set some sort of "block" for each value and this block must last for four print attempts.

For example, in my code, I would like in the a_random variable, if `Word A2` is printed, then `Word A2` will only be able to print again after four subsequent printing attempts, but I want to print only one random word among the four (and not print four words).

For example, if I print `Word A2`, the subsequent prints must be 4 random among `"Word A1", "Word A3", "Word A4", "Word A5", "Word A6", "Word A7", "Word A8"`, then on the fifth attempt it will be able to print Word A2 again (but not mandatory, because in addition to Word A2 it will be possible to print any word).

Important: I want to print only one word at a time. I don't want to print four words or more words at a time. The output I would like is only one word.

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')

def func():
    
   a = "Word A1", "Word A2", "Word A3", "Word A4", "Word A5", "Word A6", "Word A7", "Word A8"
   print("NEW")
   a_random = print(random.choice(a))
   print(" ")  
   return a_random


button = ttk.Button(root, text='Random', command=func)
button.place(x=10, y=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The simplest way to do it would be to "throw away" any result that doesn't fit your criteria, and keep calling `random.choice` until you get a good result. Another option would be to to use sets, and use set subtraction (aka difference) to remove unwanted results from the selection at each step

Comment: @NeatNit Could you show me an answer with the 2 different solutions please? I will gladly accept your answer in case it helps. Thank you

Comment: Do you mean one word per line or per run?

Comment: `but I want to print only one (1) random word among the four (and not print 4 words)` I don't understand the question: if you only print one word, then you can never have any repetition among your words. Therefore the part about not repeating doesn't matter. On the other hand, if you want to print multiple words, and have no repetition among those words, then @MarkTolonen's answer would work.

Answer (score 1):

This uses a list that keeps track of the blacklisted indices and removes those from sampling. The list will not grow larger than four items.

```
import random
import numpy as np

vocab = np.array([
    "Word A1",
    "Word A2",
    "Word A3",
    "Word A4",
    "Word A5",
    "Word A6",
    "Word A7",
    "Word A8"
])

# a list of all indices of the array
indices = np.arange(0, len(vocab))

# a list that will store blacklisted indices as long as they are forbidden (4 time steps)
blacklist = []

for i in range(10):
    # only allow values that were not used in the last for steps
    random_index = random.choice(list(set(indices) - set(blacklist)))
    # update blacklist for next run
    blacklist = [random_index] + blacklist  # add new index at the beginning
    blacklist = blacklist[0:4]  # only keep four values, remove older items
    print(vocab[random_index])
```

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong. I would like to print just one word. Your code prints me so many words

Comment: i put everything in a loop so you see many examples. You can simple remove the for loop and will get one word. Replace `10` with you desired number of samples.

Comment: @EvangelosDellas _"I would like to print just one word."_ - then why bother about repetition if you need only one word?

Comment: @Klops Your answer is not what I'm looking for. Maybe I didn't express myself well. I changed the question code. I want to get only one (1) word at a time. Can you revise your answer please? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A `deque` can be configured with a maximum length to automatically track the last four words.  Example:

```py
>>> from collections import deque
>>> last = deque(maxlen=4)
>>> last.append('word2')
>>> last.append('word3')
>>> last.append('word4')
>>> last.append('word5')
>>> last.append('word6')
>>> last.append('word6')
>>> last    # only remembers last 4 added
deque(['word3', 'word4', 'word5', 'word6'], maxlen=4)
```

This can be used to track the last words picked and retry the selection:

```py
import random
from collections import deque

_last4 = deque(maxlen=4)
words = ['Word A1', 'Word A2', 'Word A3', 'Word A4', 'Word A5', 'Word A6', 'Word A7', 'Word A8']

def get_word():
    # Assignment expression (:=) needs Python 3.8+
    while (word := random.choice(words)) in _last4:
        pass
    _last4.append(word)
    return word

for _ in range(20):
    w = get_word()
    print(f'{w}   #{" "*int(w[-1])}{w[-1]}') # with annotation
```

Output (annotated to call out spacing):

```
Word A2   #  2
Word A1   # 1
Word A6   #      6
Word A8   #        8
Word A3   #   3
Word A7   #       7
Word A1   # 1
Word A4   #    4
Word A2   #  2
Word A3   #   3
Word A8   #        8
Word A1   # 1
Word A6   #      6
Word A4   #    4
Word A3   #   3
Word A7   #       7
Word A8   #        8
Word A6   #      6
Word A2   #  2
Word A1   # 1
```

Tk Example:

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from collections import deque

_last4 = deque(maxlen=4)
words = ['Word A1', 'Word A2', 'Word A3', 'Word A4', 'Word A5', 'Word A6', 'Word A7', 'Word A8']

def get_word():
    # Assignment expression (:=) needs Python 3.8+
    while (word := random.choice(words)) in _last4:
        pass
    _last4.append(word)
    label.configure(text=word)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')

label = ttk.Label(root)
label.place(x=10, y=50)
button = ttk.Button(root, text='Random', command=get_word)
button.place(x=10, y=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your answer is not what I'm looking for. Maybe I didn't express myself well. I changed the question code. I want to get only one (1) word at a time. Can you revise your answer please? Thank you

Comment: @EvangelosDellas The `get_word` function in this answer returns exactly one word. What is the issue?

Comment: @EvangelosDellas Just hook up the get_word() function to be called by your Tk `Button` instead.  Make it write to a label.  I'll add a quick example.

Comment: @MarkTolonen If I wanted to do a test, so on every click I wanted to print the words in the Python console, what should I write? print (what?)???

Comment: @EvangelosDellas Put `input(get_word())` in the `for` loop.  Every time you hit enter it will print a new word.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Can you show it to me please and edit the answer? Thank you and sorry

Comment: @MarkTolonen 
There is no such thing as "input" in your code, so I don't understand what you are saying. I just upvoted your answer

Comment: @EvangelosDellas [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) is a built-in function...

Answer (score 1):

you can just add list and use it like queue

new code is

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')

queue = []
def func():
    global queue
    a = "Word A1", "Word A2", "Word A3", "Word A4", "Word A5", "Word A6", "Word A7", "Word A8"
    print("NEW")
    while True:
        # geting random word
        a_random = random.choice(a)
        # check for repitaion
        if not a_random in queue:
            # print word
            print(a_random)
            # push the word into the queue to stop repitaion
            queue.append(a_random)
            #check if after 4 word to allow repitaion word
            if len(queue) == 5:
                queue.pop(0)
            break

    print(" ")
    return a_random


button = ttk.Button(root, text='Random', command=func)
button.place(x=10, y=10)

root.mainloop()
```

If you are not familiar with the queue, check this [website](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/queue-in-python/)

Comment: Your answer is not what I'm looking for. Maybe I didn't express myself well. I changed the question code. I want to get only one (1) word at a time. Can you revise your answer please? Thank you

Comment: I tested your code and print Word A3, Word A2, Word A1, Word A4, Word A8, Word A5, Word A6, Word A4.Analyzing, Word A4 prints after 4 attempts from Word A4. I had asked on the fifth attempt. But now I have a doubt: in your code, each word is printed separated by 4 (or 5) attempts from the other? (or does this only apply to the first word you print?)

Comment: I ran a new test. I have printed: A5, A4, A6, A2, A1, A4, A5, A7, A8, A4, A3, A7. As you can see, A7 repeats on the fourth print attempt. An equal word should come out on the fifth attempt at printing (or more). Can you review your code please? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here's two methods:

Method 1: repeatedly call `random.choice` until you get what you want. It's a bit silly and arguably bad practice, but it works. But you have to make sure that there IS a possible valid result, otherwise it will end up in an infinite loop.

```py
import random

words = "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"
sentence_length = 20

sentence1 = []

# first method: ignore bad results
for n in range(sentence_length):
    next_word = random.choice(words)
    while next_word in sentence1[-4:]:
        # print is for your understanding:
        print("  " + " ".join(sentence1) + " -> skipping " + next_word)
        next_word = random.choice(words) 
    sentence1.append(next_word)

print(" ".join(sentence1))
```

Method 2: remove the undesired words from the list of available words for `random.choice`.

```py
# second method: remove unwanted words from allowed set
# note: this method removes multiplicity! If you want some words to be more likely, don't use sets
words_set = {x for x in words}
sentence2 = []
for n in range(sentence_length):
    valid_words = words_set.difference(sentence2[-4:])
    next_word = random.choice(list(valid_words))
    sentence2.append(next_word)

print(" ".join(sentence2))

# alternatively: using just list, not sets
# this preserves multiplicity, but *might* run slower if your list of words is very large
sentence3 = []
for n in range(sentence_length):
    valid_words = [w for w in words if w not in sentence3[-4:]]
    next_word = random.choice(list(valid_words))
    sentence3.append(next_word)

print(" ".join(sentence3))
```

Comment: Your answer is not what I'm looking for. Maybe I didn't express myself well. I changed the question code. I want to get only one (1) word at a time. Can you revise your answer please? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try leveraging [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) to reduce the repetition (though potentially it does not completely match you requirements, but can be "good enough" and should be faster):

> Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence. Used for random sampling without replacement.

```py
a = ["Word A1", "Word A2", "Word A3", "Word A4", "Word A5", "Word A6", "Word A7", "Word A8"]

window_size = 4 # should be less then size of a
curr_window = random.sample(a, window_size) # 4 random unique elements from a

# use curr_window for the next 4 random values then renew it with random.sample(a, 4)
```

Note that you still can have repetition due to "window" boundaries (i.e. "1, 2, 3, 4, **4**, not 4, not 4, not 4, ...")

**UPD**

For example (can be wrapped into a class like [iterator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator)):

```py
a = ["Word A1", "Word A2", "Word A3", "Word A4", "Word A5", "Word A6", "Word A7", "Word A8"]

window_size = 4
curr_window = random.sample(a, window_size)
curr = -1

def get_word():
   global curr, curr_window
   curr = curr + 1
   if(curr >= window_size):
       curr = 0
       curr_window = random.sample(a, window_size)
   return curr_window[curr]    

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')

def func():
   print("NEW")
   a_random = print(get_word())
   print(" ")  
   return a_random


button = ttk.Button(root, text='Random', command=func)
button.place(x=10, y=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I would like to print only one word at a time. Your code prints me 4 words

Comment: @EvangelosDellas you don't need to print the whole array at a time (as described in the code in the comment). You take it and iterate when needed (for example maintaining counter and checking that it is less then window size).

Comment: To print a single word, as I asked in the question, what should I write?

Comment: @EvangelosDellas updated the code with example.

Comment: Maybe you didn't understand what I'm asking in the question. You are very kind, but I don't want to print many Words. The output I would like is just one (1) word

Comment: @EvangelosDellas - if you are printing only one word - where repetition comes from then? =))

Comment: If I open and close the script, or if it puts a tkinter button to print (only print 1 word at a time). The repetition is in every new button click or in every opening and closing of the script. I always want to print one (1) single word at a time. For example if I click on the button I can only print Word2, if I click on the button again I can print Word2 again

Comment: I think it needs to save the letters in a file or somewhere, like the last 4 letters used ,still not clear

Comment: @EvangelosDellas in case of script - you need to save the "state" outside of it, for example in some file and this is completely different question which is much broader. In case of tkinter app - I highly suspect that it allow to maintain state between button handlers invocations, so you move the `curr`, `curr_window` and `window_size` there and  use something similar to `get_word` in the button click handler. But again - it is completely another question.

Comment: @Guru Stron Maybe I didn't express myself well. I changed the question code. I want to get only one (1) word at a time. Can you revise your answer please? Thank you :)

Comment: @EvangelosDellas try the updated code. But I would argue that this was a very easy modification that you should be able to handle yourself since `get_word` returns just one word.

Comment: @GuruStron You are kind, thank you, but there is something wrong with your code. For example I have printed Word A7, Word A3, Word A2, Word A6, Word A1, Word A8, Word A2. Analyzing, there is Word A2 printing on the fourth attempt after Word A2 is printed the first time. I didn't ask for this. EACH word should print on the fifth attempt. I tried writing window_size = 5, but that didn't fix the problem

Comment: @EvangelosDellas this was mentioned in _"Note that you still can have repetition on "window" boundaries"_ . This code reduces the repetition, if you need to have sliding window repetition removed - use the approaches wich maintain set/queue of last n words.

Comment: @GuruStron Yes, of course, I know, but there is still something wrong.

For example I have now printed Word A6, Word A2, Word A1, Word A8, Word A2.

The second Word A2 should not print. There are only 3 attempts to print between the first Word A2 and the second Word A2. That's not what I asked in the question.

The border of the window you're talking about doesn't matter in this case

Comment: @EvangelosDellas everything is "right". You have two windows, so you can get up to 2  `A2`'s.

Comment: @GuruStron It's not right and I don't want 2 windows. I'm sorry you didn't understand

Comment: @EvangelosDellas I perfectly understand, but since the main goal is to reduce repetition I have decided to suggest this approach.