# distribute value randomly to elements of a list

Tags: python, random, distribution

I want to randomize the elements of `rand_skill = []` in a way, that the sum of all elements is always equal to the variable `skill_points`. Further, I'd like to be able to influence the distribution, by using `tag_list = []`, to make specific elements of `rand_list` more likely to be bigger.

```
def roll_talents(skill_points, tag_list):
    talents = []
    # FIGHT
    talents[0] = 0 + get_attribute_mod(attributes[3]) + get_attribute_mod(attributes[4]) + rand_skill [0]
    talents[1] = 0 + get_attribute_mod(attributes[4]) + rand_skill [1]
    talents[2] = 0 + get_attribute_mod(attributes[3]) + rand_skill [2]
    talents[3] = 0 + get_attribute_mod(attributes[0]) + rand_skill [3]
    talents[4] = 0 + get_attribute_mod(attributes[5]) + rand_skill [4]
    talents[5] = 0 + rand_skill [5]
    # COMMUNIKATION
    talents[6] = 0 + get_attribute_mod(attributes[2]) + rand_skill [6]
    talents[7] = 0 + get_attribute_mod(attributes[3]) + rand_skill [7]
    talents[8] = 0 + get_attribute_mod(attributes[6]) + rand_skill [8]
    talents[9] = 0 + get_attribute_mod(attributes[1]) + rand_skill [9]
    # [...]
    return talents
```

I tried to use a `for` loop, that adds `1` to a random element of `rand_skill`, until the added value equaled `skill_points`, but that seems very inefficient and crude.

Comment: Have a look on random package in python. There are methods like choices that allow to weight random sample from a list.

Comment: [A weighted version of random.choice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3679694/19381879) this was what I was looking for, thank you for the key words.