# Biased Random Choice from a class - python

Tags: python, class, random, range

I have for loop, and I need to modify it as follows:
If we have CarTypes A or B:
It will randomly choose methods which are AA, BB, CC, and DD.
However, I want the choice to have a bias. So, I want the choice of Method DD will be less than the choice of the rest of methods AA, BB, and CC.

Also, If we have CarTypes C or D:
It will randomly choose methods which are AA, BB, CC, DD, EE, and FF.
However, I want the choice of Method DD, EE, and FF will be more than the choice of the rest of methods AA, BB, and CC.
Any suggestions please?

```
import random
from enum import Enum
Steps = 11
class CarTypes(Enum):
    A   = 0
    B   = 1
    C   = 2
    D   = 3   
class Methods(Enum):
    AA = 0
    BB = 1
    CC = 2
    DD = 3
    EE = 4
    FF = 5
    GG = 6
        
for iStep in range(Steps):
    Number = 0
    
    if (CarTypes.A.value or CarTypes.B.value):
        N = random.randrange(0, Methods.EE.value)
        if   ( N == Methods.AA.value ):
            Number =+ 1            
        elif ( N == Methods.BB.value ):  
            Number =+ 1         
        elif ( N == Methods.CC.value ):  
            Number =+ 1        
        elif ( N == Methods.DD.value ): 
            Number =+ 1

    elif (CarTypes.C.value or CarTypes.D.value):
        nEvent = random.randrange(0, Methods.GG.value)
        
        if   ( N == Methods.AA.value ):
            Number =+ 1            
        elif ( N == Methods.BB.value ):  
            Number =+ 1      
        elif ( N == Methods.CC.value ):  
            Number =+ 1         
        elif ( N == Methods.DD.value ):  
            Number =+ 1                
        elif ( N == Methods.EE.value ):  
            Number =+ 1         
        elif ( N == Methods.FF.value ): 
            Number =+ 1
```

Comment: [A weighted version of random.choice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3679694/11082165) might be a better dupe target.

Comment: Also, do note that enums are iterable, so you can just sample `list(Methods)` instead of converting to and from integer values.

Comment: `CarTypes.A.value or CarTypes.B.value` is probably not doing what you think it does. That expression is always `True`.

Comment: Another tip: if there's inherent significance to certain enum variants, you might want to consider adding a method to the enum instead of checking for those variants repeatedly in your code. For example, something like `def is_foo(self): return self in (Methods.A, Methods.B, Methods.C, Methods.D)` to replace the first `if`/`elif` block.