# Normalize list of floats to probabilities

Tags: python, numpy, probability, normalization

I have a list of probability weights like `weights = [3, 7, 4, 2]` and I want to **normalize** it so that `sum(weights) == 1`.

This can be later used for something like "[A weighted version of random.choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679694/a-weighted-version-of-random-choice)" with [numpy.random.choice](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)

Currently I am doing something like:

```
norm_one = sum(weights)
probabilities = [x / norm_one for x in weights]
```

I am wondering if there is any problem with what I am doing since floating points are represented with a finite number of bits and the sum of the list might not equal 1 and if there is a builtin function to normalize either a list or a numpy.array that I should use instead (or any better approach)

Comment: Why not use NumPy for the calculations?

Comment: Just because I am not too confident with numpy, but an answer with numpy is also accepted

Comment: Hmm, if you're not confident with it for a sum and division, are you sure you want to use it at all?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [How to make numpy array column sum up to 1](/q/43644320/4518341). (Where your data is 1D, you can drop the `axis` argument in Divakar's answer.)

Comment: @wjandrea yes and no. This replicates my example in numpy, my question is if there is any builtin I can use to do this operation either in numpy or with lists of floats so I can make my code more readable.

Comment: @Umberto To make your code more readable, just write a function, like `def norm(a): return a / a.sum(keepdims=True)`

Comment: @Umberto I'm not an expert myself, but I found [another solution, `sklearn.preprocessing.normalize(a, norm='l1')`](/a/22546877/4518341), but it's exclusively 2D

Comment: BTW, to find these, I googled `numpy array normalize to sum 1`

Comment: Your comments make it seem like you want to make your code more readable -- your code is quite readable as-is, I wouldn't add dependencies like numpy or sklearn if all you want to do with them is this normalization. If these arrays are large, numpy will be useful since it'll move the calculation out of slow python code. You're still going to run into floating-point precision errors as long as you use floating point numbers

Comment: @wjandrea I'll go with sklearn, I am pretty surprised by the fact that there is no equivalent in the built in packages

Comment: If you are worried about accuracy, the first thing to do would be replacing that naive sum with [`math.fsum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html?highlight=fsum#math.fsum)

Comment: It's unspecific. Provide a specific case where you have to deal with the round-off errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you are correct, it can happen that the sum would equal `1 +- very_small_number` but the packages like Numpy and Pandas do not care about that and it will just work (the magic of python).

As other have pointed out in the comments use numpy for normalization

1. It will be much faster when dealing with large arrays
2. It will be less verbose

Code:

```
import numpy as np

weights = np.array([5, 18, 7])
probabilities = weights / weights.sum()
```