# How to improve the "randomness" of the result returned by a method that is designed to place objects in a random order in a given structure?

Tags: python, oop

I made a simple application that allows a teacher to seat pupils in a classroom.

Classes:

```
class Pupil:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Seat:
    def __init__(self, column, desk):
        self.column = column
        self.desk = desk
        self.pupil = None

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Seat - Desk: {self.desk}, Column: {self.column}, Pupil: {self.pupil}"


class Classroom:
    def __init__(self, columns, desks):
        self.columns = columns
        self.desks = desks
        self.seats = self.create_seats()

    def create_seats(self):
        seats = defaultdict(list)
        for i in range(self.columns):
            for j in range(self.desks):
                seats[i].append(Seat(i, j))
        return seats

    def assign_pupils_to_seats(self, pupils):
        shuffled_pupils = random.sample(pupils, k=len(pupils))
        seats_with_pupils = defaultdict(list)

        keys = range(self.columns)
        remaining_desks = self.desks
        while remaining_desks > 0:
            for key in keys:
                seat = self.seats[key][-remaining_desks]
                try:
                    setattr(seat, 'pupil', shuffled_pupils.pop())
                except IndexError:
                    print('No more pupils available.')
                seats_with_pupils[key].append(seat)
            remaining_desks -= 1
        return seats_with_pupils
```

A method that allows you to “seat” pupils in a random order is *assign_pupils_to_seats(pupils: list)*.

The problem is that I don't think this method does what it's supposed to do. Namely: I make 10 seating arrangements in a row, and for, for example, this classroom configuration, I get the following seating arrangements (for ease of understanding - for one of the students):

```
_  _     _    _     _  _
_  _     _    4     10 3
8  _     _    _     _  5
_  _     1,9  _     _  _
_  _     _  6,7     2  _

       whiteboard
```

Explanation: this particular class has the following configuration:

- 3 rows (vertical);
- 2 "variants" in each row (vertical);
- 5 horizontal rows of desks (each of which can accommodate 2 pupils and has 2 "variants" respectively).

That is, the same pupil can sit in the same row more times (suppose the teacher seats pupils once a month). Or, after several seating arrangements, he (she) may end up in the same place (and sometimes even in a row - see seating arrangements 6 and 7).

My question is, is it possible to optimize the "randomness" of the seating?

I tried shuffling not only the pupil in a list, but also the columns ("variants") and even the order in which seats within the same column would receive a pupil, but none of this produced any qualitative improvement.

Comment: How are you quantifying randomness? Is it purely on the feeling? True randomness often does not "feel" random enough.

Comment: matszwecja, I mean how can we make the distribution of pupils more even and less repetitive from seating to seating - in the same classroom configuration and for the same group of pupils. So that the same pupil will sit in all 3 rows approximately the same number of times (30%) and on different desks in 10 seating arrangements.

Comment: You are confusing random and uniform distribution I think.

Comment: matszwecja, look at the example, please: in 10 seating arrangements, he sat mostly on the 2nd and 3rd rows, and only once on 1st. Also, in 10 seating arrangements, he ended up in the same place twice.

Comment: JonSG, I think so. That's why I added this comments.

Comment: That is what random looks like.

Comment: Random means that any given student could sit in the same seat every observation (though highly improbable). What we want here is to introduce some uniformity to the seating so that once a given student had been assigned a row and column then in the future the next assignment would down weight those options. Perhaps `numpy.choice()` or `random.choice()` with a specification of the weights would help

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679694/a-weighted-version-of-random-choice for ideas

Comment: JonSG, how to improve distribution uniformity?

Comment: Check out [numpy.random.uniform](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html)