# How can I make a random choice according to probabilities stored in a list (weighted random distribution)?

Tags: python, random, probability, weighted

Given a list of probabilities like:

```
P = [0.10, 0.25, 0.60, 0.05]
```

(I can ensure that the sum of all the variables in P is always 1)

How can I write a function that randomly returns a valid index, according to the values in the list? In other words, for this specific input, I want it to return `0` 10% of the time, `1` 25% of the time, `2` 60% of the time and `3` the remainind 5% of the time.

Comment: Actually, starting from Python 3.6 there is `random.choices` (note the 's' at the end) which allows submitting relative weights.

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine would you please add an answer about this?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352670/weighted-random-selection-with-and-without-replacement. I think this question is probably the better canonical.

Comment: There is also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140787 to consider, as the specific case of repeated sampling without replacement is somewhat trickier.

Comment: Maybe it's better to edit the `random.choices` information into the top answer, since the interface is substantially the same.

Answer (score 63):

You can easily achieve this with numpy. It has a [choice](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html?highlight=random%20choice#numpy.random.choice) function which accepts the parameter of probabilities.

```
np.random.choice(
  ['pooh', 'rabbit', 'piglet', 'Christopher'], 
  5,
  p=[0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3]
)
```

Comment: Concise, although I think `numpy` is overkill here, especially if the script had no dependencies beyond the standard library

Answer (score 15):

Basically, make a [cumulative probability distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) (CDF) array. Basically, the value of the CDF for a given index is equal to the sum of all values in P equal to or less than that index. Then you generate a random number between 0 and 1 and do a binary search (or linear search if you want). Here's some simple code for it.

```
from bisect import bisect
from random import random

P = [0.10,0.25,0.60,0.05]

cdf = [P[0]]
for i in xrange(1, len(P)):
    cdf.append(cdf[-1] + P[i])

random_ind = bisect(cdf,random())
```

of course you can generate a bunch of random indices with something like

```
rs = [bisect(cdf, random()) for i in xrange(20)]
```

yielding

```
[2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

(results will, and should vary). Of course, binary search is rather unnecessary for so few of possible indices, but definitely recommended for distributions with more possible indices.

Answer (score 12):

Hmm interesting, how about...

1. Generate a number between 0 and 1.
2. Walk the list substracting the probability of each item from your number.
3. Pick the item that, after substraction, took your number down to 0 or below.

That's simple, O(n) and should work :)

Comment: It will help if the probabilities are pre-sorted in a descending way - the iteration is likely to terminate faster.

Answer (score 6):

This problem is equivalent to sampling from a [**categorical distribution**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_distribution).  This distribution is commonly conflated with the multinomial distribution which models the result of multiple samples from a categorical distribution.

In numpy, it is easy to sample from the multinomial distribution using [numpy.random.multinomial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.multinomial.html), but a specific categorical version of this does not exist.  However, it can be accomplished by sampling from the multinomial distribution with a single trial and then returning the non-zero element in the output.

```
import numpy as np
pvals = [0.10,0.25,0.60,0.05]
ind = np.where(np.random.multinomial(1,pvals))[0][0]
```

Comment: I think using argmax() instead of where()[0][0] is simpler and does the same.

Answer (score 3):

```
import random

probs = [0.1, 0.25, 0.6, 0.05]
r = random.random()
index = 0
while(r >= 0 and index < len(probs)):
  r -= probs[index]
  index += 1
print index - 1
```

Comment: Haha and here I thought ~2 seconds before you posted that I was being original

Comment: This always takes O(n) time where n is the len(probs). Can we do better?

Comment: @Sush Yes: we can sort the probs and do a binary search. This would reduce to O(log n).

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Python 3.6 there is the `choices` method (note the 's' at the end) in `random`

Quoting from the documentation:

> random.choices(population, weights=None, *, cum_weights=None, k=1)
> Return a k sized list of elements chosen from the population with replacement

So the solution would look like this:

```
>> choices(['option1', 'option2', 'option3', 'option4'], [0.10, 0.25, 0.60, 0.05])
```