# Choose dictionary key randomly based on value

Tags: python, dictionary, random, probability

I have a dictionary that looks like this: `{"one": 5, "two": 1, "three": 25, "four": 14}`

I want to choose a key from the dictionary in proportion to the values, i.e. "three" would have the highest chance, then "four" then "one" and then "two". I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437250/choose-list-variable-given-probability-of-each-variable) question however it seems to be specific to when the numbers add up to 1.

I've really no idea how to start, help would be appreciated.

Comment: @PeterO. Perhaps, I'll look into it

Comment: You can make your numbers add up to one if you divide by the sum of all the values. `sum(mydict.values())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) with the `weights` parameter:

> random.choices(population, weights=None, *, cum_weights=None, k=1)
>
> Return a k sized list of elements chosen from the population with
>   replacement. If the population is empty, raises IndexError.
>
> If a weights sequence is specified, selections are made according to
>   the relative weights. Alternatively, if a cum_weights sequence is
>   given, the selections are made according to the cumulative weights

```
import random

d = {"one": 5, "two": 1, "three": 25, "four": 14}
keys = list(d.keys())
values = list(d.values())
random_key = random.choices(keys, weights=values)

print(random_key)
# ['three']
```