# Generate values in R and Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to generate dummy data with some probability. Let say I want to have dummy data about people by gender. I already prepare this in R and you can see my code line below.

```
gender = sample(x=c("M","F"), prob = c(.6, .4),size=100,replace=TRUE)
```

Now I want to prepare the same thing but now in Python in Pandas Data Frame. Can anybody help me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.random.choice`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437250/how-can-i-make-a-random-choice-according-to-probabilities-stored-in-a-list-weig) , `replace` is `True` by default.

```py
>>> np.random.choice(a=["M", "F"], size=100, p=[0.6, 0.4])

array(['F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M',
       'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'F',
       'F', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'F',
       'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M',
       'F', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M',
       'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F',
       'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F',
       'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F'], dtype='<U1')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. `random.choices` gets `k` choices from the iterable provided:

```py
import random
print(random.choices("MF", weights=[.6,.4], k=100))
```

Testing:

```py
>>> l = random.choices("MF", weights=[.6,.4], k=100)
>>> l
['M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M']
>>> l.count("M")
60
>>> l.count("F")
40
```

Comment: It doesn't take probabilities in account

Comment: I don't see it being fixed

Comment: @ThePyGuy - oops, I updated the code, but not the output. I've updated both now.

Comment: Can you tell me how it takes care of probabilities `.6, .4`?

Comment: There is `weights` parameter in `random.choice` which you can probably use to define the probabilities, docs at https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice

Comment: @ThePyGuy - it's because there are 3 `M`s and 2 `F`s, so `M` has a 60% chance of appearing, and `F` has a 40% chance

Comment: But, the weights parameter is probably better so I updated my answer.