# Picking objects from a vector with defined probabilities on matlab/octave

Tags: matlab, list, random, octave

Is there any function on Matlab/Octave that randomly picks a value from a list accordingly to a given probability?

For example: we have the vector [1 3 7]. The function I am looking for should pick one of those numbers with probability .25 for 1, .35 for 3 and .4 for 7.

I am trying to implement it myself, but I'd like to know if there is some build-in function for the next time I need something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a function statistics toolbox called [`randsample`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html). It samples `k` values out of `n` with replacement (without replacement is not supported). You want to select one value, which can be done as follows:

```
nSamplesToChoose=1;
weightVector=[0.2 0.5 0.3];%weights some to one so as to represent probability distribution
yourArray=[5 6 7]; %length of the array should be same as the length of weightVector.
chosenSample=randsample(yourArray,nSamplesToChoose,true,weightVector)
```

P.S. I encourage you to implement this by yourself. You may refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463561/weighted-random-selection-from-array) question.

Comment: I did implement it 
`function pick = randompick(vector, probs)
  r = rand()
  c = 0
  for i in 1:size(vector)(2)
    if c < r and r < c + probs(i)
      pick = vector(i)
      c = c + probs(i)
    end
  end
endfunction
`
 I just wanted to know if there was anything don in case I ever need it again. randsample sounds perfect, many thanks :-)

Comment: It seems that replacement is supported. [http://octave.sourceforge.net/statistics/function/randsample.html](http://octave.sourceforge.net/statistics/function/randsample.html). _Returns k random elements from a vector v with n elements, sampled without or with replacement._

Comment: Note that _weightVector_ has not to sum 1, so if you mean probabilities, you must make sure that it does sum one. For instance, the example of Parag, _`weightVector=[0.25 0.5 0.7];`_ does not sum 1, thus its values do not represent the probabilities of the elements. The actual probabilities in that case are `[0.25 0.5 0.7] / 1.45`.

Comment: @JB I have edited the answer so that weights sum to one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you described is like a Generalized Bernoulli Distribution. So, you can use the Multinomial Distribution to generate this data.

The MATLAB help page is [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mnrnd.html).

In your case, `n=1` and `p=[.25 .35 .4]`.

```
mnrnd(n,p)
```

will return a `1 x 3` vector which has only one non-zero element which corresponds to the random variable which should be chosen.

---

TL;DR Version:

To generate the required output, you can simply do `dot([1 3 7], mnrnd(1,[.25 .35 .4]))`