# How to distribute visitors based on weight

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model

In my application I have models `Post` & `Image` & I use `nested_attributes` for `Image`.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post, :counter_cache => true
```

The purpose of my application is, on each *visit/visitor*, I only **show** **ONE** of the `images` on that post to user. Currently I just pick a `random` image.

```
rnd = @post.images.sample
```

This works fine, but what I'm looking for is to **Distribute** visitors based on `weight` I add to each **image**.

Default `weight` can be **10**. For instance, I have 6 *images* on that post & `weights` are:

```
Image 1 => weight 10
Image 2 => weight 20
Image 3 => weight 50
Image 4 => weight 30
Image 5 => weight 60
Image 6 => weight 10
```

What I want to achieve is to distribute visitors to each image based on `image weights`, so `Image 5` would get most of the visitors but we still send visitors to `Image 1` & other images.

I haven't yet added `weight` to `images` so it can be changed to whatever needed.

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463561/weighted-random-selection-from-array
There are multiple solution, depending of performance needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this `gem`: [weighted_distribution](https://github.com/jonathanswenson/weighted_distribution). I ran some tests and it works very good.

Only important thing is that you `array`, has to look like, which is a `hash`:

```
{'object-1' => weight, 'object-2' => weight, 'object-3' => weight, 'object-4' => weight}
```

*My code:*

```
suits = @post.images.pluck(:id, :weight).to_h
```