# How can I randomly weight an element from an array and then pick it based on those weights?

Tags: arrays, bash, random

I want to pseudo-randomly pick one element from an array of 5 elements: I want to control the occurrence probability of each of those 5 elements.

**Example**: I have an array like this: `[A B C D E]`

- I want the probability to pick A: 0.10 (10%)
- I want the probability to pick B: 0.10 (10%)
- I want the probability to pick C: 0.20 (20%)
- I want the probability to pick D: 0.20 (20%)
- I want the probability to pick E: 0.40 (40%)

I have seen that I can weight a random selection from an array here: [Weighted random selection from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463561/weighted-random-selection-from-array).

How can I weight elements contained in an array like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use the bash builtin variable RANDOM, with a little arithmetic

```
weighted_selection() {
    local ary=("$@")
    case $(( RANDOM % 10 )) in
        0) index=0 ;;      # one out of ten
        1) index=1 ;;      # one out of ten
        2|3) index=2 ;;    # two out of ten
        4|5) index=3 ;;    # two out of ten
        *) index=4 ;;      # remaining is four out of ten
    esac
    echo ${ary[index]}
}
```

Let's test it:

```
a=(A B C D E)
declare -A count
for ((i=1; i<1000; i++)); do
    (( count[$(weighted_selection "${a[@]}")]++ ))
done
declare -p count
```

outputs

```
declare -A count='([A]="99" [B]="100" [C]="211" [D]="208" [E]="381" )'
```

Comment: `RANDOM` ranges from 0 to 32767, so this really produces a distribution like 10.006%/10.006%/20.012%/20.012%/39.99%. If that difference matters (and it probably shouldn't), you could do something like `x=32768; until (( x < 32760 )); x=$RANDOM`, then check `$x % 10`.

Comment: does it have go version for this algo?