# How can I assign a value to a random element of 2D array in C

Tags: c

For example, there is an array like this ==> `array[10][10]`

I want to pick a random element of this array like `array[5][7]` and assign it to 0.

How can I do it?

Comment: if its random `array[5][7] = 0;` thats it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Weighted random selection from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463561/weighted-random-selection-from-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be something like:

```
srand((unsigned) time());  // For different result every second
int x = rand() % 10;
int y = rand() % 10;
array[x][y] = 0;
```